# Dsolve too slow -- is there anyway around?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to solve:

```
DSolve[{Cn'[t] == CP[t]*kr - P*Cn[t]*kf, 
        CP'[t] == Cn[t]*P*kf + 2*CPP[t]*kr - P*CP[t]*kf - CP[t]*kr, 
        CPP'[t] == CP[t]*P*kf + 3*CPPP[t]*kr - P*CPP[t]*kf - 2*CPP[t]*kr, 
        CPPP'[t] == CPP[t]*P*kf + 4*CPPPP[t]*kr - P*CPPP[t]*kf - 3*CPPP[t]*kr, 
        CPPPP'[t] == CPPP[t]*P*kf - 4*CPPPP[t]*kr, CP[0] == 0, CPP[0] == 0, 
        CPPP[0] == 0, CPPPP[0] == Chp, Cn[0] == Chn}, 
      {Cn[t], CP[t], CPP[t], CPPP[t], CPPPP[t]}, t]
```

*Mathematica* 9 did not give a result overnight and ate up all the memory (~6g). However it can solve

```
DSolve[{Cn'[t] == CP[t]*kr - P*Cn[t]*kf, 
        CP'[t] == Cn[t]*P*kf + CPP[t]*kr - P*CP[t]*kf - CP[t]*kr, 
        CPP'[t] == CP[t]*P*kf + CPPP[t]*kr - P*CPP[t]*kf - CPP[t]*kr, 
        CPPP'[t] == CPP[t]*P*kf + CPPPP[t]*kr - P*CPPP[t]*kf - CPPP[t]*kr, 
        CPPPP'[t] == CPPP[t]*P*kf - CPPPP[t]*kr, CP[0] == 0, CPP[0] == 0, 
        CPPP[0] == 0, CPPPP[0] == chp, Cn[0] == chn},
      {Cn[t], CP[t], CPP[t], CPPP[t], CPPPP[t]}, t]
```

in hours. I am not very familiar with *Mathematica*. I wonder if there is a way to solve this system (the former one).

Comment: Do you need a closed form solution or a numerical one would do the trick ?

Comment: Can you specify what `kr`,`kf` and `P` are? If those are constants, i.e. independent of t, the system should be easily solvable in a matter of seconds, because it would be linear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Yes kr, kf and P are constants with respect to t.  I added SetAttributes[{kr, kf, P, chn, chp}, Constant] before the DSolve expression. It has been working for several hours now and still no result yet. It is best if I can have an explicit solution to this. If not, is there a way to do numerical fittings with my experimental data to derive kr, kf and P (parameters).

Comment: @Weiwei Something like: [How to fit...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property of your system of equations :

```
eqs = Simplify[{Cn'[t] == CP[t]*kr - P*Cn[t]*kf, 
                CP'[t] == Cn[t]*P*kf + 2*CPP[t]*kr - P*CP[t]*kf - CP[t]*kr, 
                CPP'[t] == CP[t]*P*kf + 3*CPPP[t]*kr - P*CPP[t]*kf - 2*CPP[t]*kr, 
                CPPP'[t] == CPP[t]*P*kf + 4*CPPPP[t]*kr - P*CPPP[t]*kf - 3*CPPP[t]*kr, 
                CPPPP'[t] == CPPP[t]*P*kf - 4*CPPPP[t]*kr}];
```

If you sum all the right-hand sides then you get :

```
FullSimplify[
 (CP[t]*kr - P*Cn[t]*kf) + 
 (Cn[t]*P*kf + 2*CPP[t]*kr - P*CP[t]*kf - CP[t]*kr) + 
 (CP[t]*P*kf + 3*CPPP[t]*kr - P*CPP[t]*kf - 2*CPP[t]*kr) + 
 (CPP[t]*P*kf + 4*CPPPP[t]*kr - P*CPPP[t]*kf - 3*CPPP[t]*kr) + 
 (CPPP[t]*P*kf - 4*CPPPP[t]*kr)]
 (* 0 *)
```

This means that the sum of all your functions `Cn[t] + CP[t] + CPP[t] + CPPP[t] + CPPPP[t]` is a constant, which equals (for instance) the value at `t=0`. We can use this information to get rid of `Cn[t]` :

```
subs = {Cn[t] -> (Chn + Chp) - (CP[t] + CPP[t] + CPPP[t] + CPPPP[t]), 
        Cn'[t] -> D[(Chn + Chp) - (CP[t] + CPP[t] + CPPP[t] + CPPPP[t]), t]};

eqs2 = FullSimplify[eqs[[2 ;;]] /. subs];

sol = DSolve[Join[eqs2, {CP[0] == 0, CPP[0] == 0, CPPP[0] == 0, CPPPP[0] == Chp}], 
             {CP[t], CPP[t], CPPP[t], CPPPP[t]}, t];
```

This runs quickly, however the result has a lot of `RootSum` objects.

Checks :

```
(* CP[0] *)
FullSimplify[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. t -> 0]
(* 0 *)

(* CPPPP[0] *)
FullSimplify[sol[[1, 4, 2]] /. t -> 0]
(* Chp *)

(* Cn[0] *)
FullSimplify[(Chn + Chp) - Total[sol[[1, All, 2]] /. t -> 0]]
(* Chn *)
```