# Multi-Fitting with Nonlinear model

Tags: fitting, data

I want to fit experimental data by the H-N model.
Here is the H-N model:
$$\text{EHN}(T)\text{=}\text{E$\infty $}+\frac{\text{E0}-\text{E$\infty $}}{\left(1+\left(i \omega\tau(T_g)10^{-\frac{\text{C1} (T-\text{Tg})}{\text{C2}+(T-\text{Tg})}}\right)^{\alpha }\right)^{\beta }}$$

Here is my data and code.

```
   dataRe={{135., 2286.88}, {136., 1889.46}, {137., 1567.42}, {138., 
          1294.73}, {139., 1081.55}, {140., 902.773}, {141., 761.623}, {142., 
          643.534}, {143., 550.366}, {144., 470.925}, {145., 405.269}, {146., 
          348.847}, {147., 303.248}, {148., 263.789}, {149., 230.926}, {150., 
          202.368}, {151., 178.676}, {152., 158.557}, {153., 142.725}, {154., 
          129.218}, {155., 118.192}, {156., 108.735}, {157., 101.272}, {158., 
          94.8359}, {159., 89.3741}, {160., 84.4597}, {161., 80.1335}, {162., 
          76.1632}, {163., 72.6128}, {164., 69.2969}, {165., 66.227}, {166., 
          63.3502}, {167., 60.7664}, {168., 58.3432}, {169., 56.0645}, {170., 
          53.8886}, {171., 51.8571}, {172., 49.9009}, {173., 48.014}, {174., 
          46.1953}, {175., 44.4969}, {176., 42.8668}, {177., 41.3076}, {178., 
          39.7966}, {179., 38.3511}, {180., 36.9621}, {181., 35.6673}, {182., 
          34.4443}, {183., 33.3239}, {184., 32.2584}, {185., 31.245}, {186., 
          30.2813}, {187., 29.4031}, {188., 28.5708}, {189., 27.781}, {190., 
          27.0241}, {191., 26.3191}, {192., 25.6392}, {193., 24.975}, {194., 
          24.3329}, {195., 23.7381}, {196., 23.1738}, {197., 22.6451}, {198., 
          22.1308}, {199., 21.6239}, {200., 21.1439}, {201., 20.7245}, {202., 
          20.3002}, {203., 19.8216}, {204., 19.3485}, {205., 18.9218}, {206., 
          18.5166}, {207., 18.1276}, {208., 17.7492}, {209., 17.3845}, {210., 
          17.0318}, {211., 16.6938}, {212., 16.3641}, {213., 16.0424}, {214., 
          15.7233}, {215., 15.4063}, {216., 15.0967}, {217., 14.8008}, {218., 
          14.5269}, {219., 14.2817}, {220., 14.0376}, {221., 13.7849}, {222., 
          13.5334}, {223., 13.288}, {224., 13.0538}, {225., 12.831}, {226., 
          12.6145}, {227., 12.4025}, {228., 12.1932}, {229., 11.9889}, {230., 
          11.8003}, {231., 11.622}, {232., 11.442}, {233., 11.2606}, {234., 
          11.0808}, {235., 10.9046}, {236., 10.7371}, {237., 10.577}, {238., 
          10.4275}, {239., 10.2802}, {240., 10.1313}, {241., 9.98528}, {242., 
          9.84445}, {243., 9.70511}, {244., 9.56583}, {245., 9.42439}, {246., 
          9.28424}, {247., 9.16163}, {248., 9.05307}, {249., 8.94078}, {250., 
          8.82361}, {251., 8.70563}, {252., 8.58908}, {253., 8.47813}, {254., 
          8.37066}, {255., 8.26599}, {256., 8.16324}, {257., 8.06268}, {258., 
          7.9627}, {259., 7.86389}, {260., 7.77106}, {261., 7.68272}, {262., 
          7.59522}, {263., 7.50776}, {264., 7.4199}, {265., 7.33254}, {266., 
          7.24746}, {267., 7.16453}, {268., 7.0849}, {269., 7.00582}, {270., 
          6.92552}, {271., 6.84306}, {272., 6.76014}, {273., 6.68684}, {274., 
          6.62505}, {275., 6.56069}, {276., 6.4861}, {277., 6.4139}, {278., 
          6.34826}, {279., 6.28453}, {280., 6.2223}, {281., 6.16394}, {282., 
          6.10795}, {283., 6.04993}, {284., 5.99424}, {285., 5.94735}, {286., 
          5.90123}, {287., 5.84622}, {288., 5.78872}, {289., 5.74026}, {290., 
          5.69521}, {291., 5.65082}, {292., 5.60682}, {293., 5.56378}, {294., 
          5.52176}, {295., 5.48153}, {296., 5.44198}, {297., 5.40113}, {298., 
          5.36029}, {299., 5.32389}, {300., 5.29061}, {301., 5.25599}, {302., 
          5.22026}, {303., 5.18636}, {304., 5.15429}, {305., 5.12238}, {306., 
          5.09002}, {307., 5.05626}, {308., 5.0215}, {309., 4.9884}, {310., 
          4.95724}, {311., 4.9259}, {312., 4.89414}, {313., 4.86346}, {314., 
          4.83431}, {315., 4.80636}, {316., 4.77938}, {317., 4.75121}, {318., 
          4.72102}, {319., 4.69132}, {320., 4.66365}, {321., 4.63793}, {322., 
          4.61535}, {323., 4.5939}, {324., 4.57255}, {325., 4.55129}, {326., 
          4.53031}, {327., 4.50947}, {328., 4.48862}, {329., 4.46747}, {330., 
          4.44536}, {331., 4.42347}, {332., 4.40477}, {333., 4.3878}, {334., 
          4.36821}};
    dataIm={{135., 887.339}, {136., 797.248}, {137., 701.968}, {138., 
      608.569}, {139., 523.492}, {140., 445.966}, {141., 379.817}, {142., 
      322.098}, {143., 274.838}, {144., 234.408}, {145., 201.682}, {146., 
      173.669}, {147., 150.826}, {148., 130.956}, {149., 114.338}, {150., 
      99.8744}, {151., 87.8489}, {152., 77.4709}, {153., 69.0043}, {154., 
      61.7297}, {155., 55.8849}, {156., 50.8427}, {157., 46.6994}, {158., 
      43.0493}, {159., 39.9282}, {160., 37.1165}, {161., 34.6505}, {162., 
      32.3913}, {163., 30.3725}, {164., 28.5008}, {165., 26.8072}, {166., 
      25.2321}, {167., 23.8052}, {168., 22.4737}, {169., 21.258}, {170., 
      20.1175}, {171., 19.0709}, {172., 18.0847}, {173., 17.1751}, {174., 
      16.3173}, {175., 15.5259}, {176., 14.7758}, {177., 14.076}, {178., 
      13.4098}, {179., 12.7869}, {180., 12.1926}, {181., 11.6359}, {182., 
      11.1054}, {183., 10.6106}, {184., 10.141}, {185., 9.7062}, {186., 
      9.29656}, {187., 8.922}, {188., 8.57166}, {189., 8.25434}, {190., 
      7.95882}, {191., 7.69154}, {192., 7.44172}, {193., 7.21152}, {194., 
      6.99187}, {195., 6.78149}, {196., 6.57857}, {197., 6.38792}, {198., 
      6.20788}, {199., 6.0449}, {200., 5.89388}, {201., 5.758}, {202., 
      5.62656}, {203., 5.49434}, {204., 5.36374}, {205., 5.23765}, {206., 
      5.11653}, {207., 5.00326}, {208., 4.89584}, {209., 4.79588}, {210., 
      4.70075}, {211., 4.61033}, {212., 4.52086}, {213., 4.43049}, {214., 
      4.33572}, {215., 4.23482}, {216., 4.13749}, {217., 4.04895}, {218., 
      3.96654}, {219., 3.89063}, {220., 3.81765}, {221., 3.74721}, {222., 
      3.67986}, {223., 3.61563}, {224., 3.55026}, {225., 3.48314}, {226., 
      3.41624}, {227., 3.34984}, {228., 3.28314}, {229., 3.2159}, {230., 
      3.14784}, {231., 3.08}, {232., 3.01543}, {233., 2.95542}, {234., 
      2.90456}, {235., 2.85808}, {236., 2.81372}, {237., 2.76943}, {238., 
      2.72368}, {239., 2.67735}, {240., 2.6309}, {241., 2.58498}, {242., 
      2.54007}, {243., 2.49639}, {244., 2.45405}, {245., 2.41249}, {246., 
      2.37127}, {247., 2.32927}, {248., 2.28662}, {249., 2.24441}, {250., 
      2.20277}, {251., 2.16184}, {252., 2.12168}, {253., 2.0829}, {254., 
      2.04515}, {255., 2.00862}, {256., 1.97252}, {257., 1.93656}, {258., 
      1.90105}, {259., 1.8665}, {260., 1.83418}, {261., 1.80359}, {262., 
      1.77372}, {263., 1.74444}, {264., 1.71617}, {265., 1.68854}, {266., 
      1.66149}, {267., 1.63461}, {268., 1.60756}, {269., 1.5805}, {270., 
      1.55363}, {271., 1.52752}, {272., 1.50251}, {273., 1.47878}, {274., 
      1.45619}, {275., 1.43259}, {276., 1.40649}, {277., 1.38075}, {278., 
      1.35628}, {279., 1.33193}, {280., 1.30753}, {281., 1.28371}, {282., 
      1.26006}, {283., 1.23519}, {284., 1.21085}, {285., 1.18961}, {286., 
      1.16996}, {287., 1.15244}, {288., 1.13717}, {289., 1.12452}, {290., 
      1.11253}, {291., 1.10009}, {292., 1.08708}, {293., 1.07289}, {294., 
      1.05803}, {295., 1.04329}, {296., 1.02881}, {297., 1.01485}, {298., 
      1.00133}, {299., 0.98825}, {300., 0.97555}, {301., 0.96326}, {302., 
      0.95127}, {303., 0.93939}, {304., 0.92759}, {305., 0.91595}, {306., 
      0.90446}, {307., 0.89313}, {308., 0.88195}, {309., 0.87097}, {310., 
      0.86024}, {311., 0.84998}, {312., 0.84021}, {313., 0.83063}, {314., 
      0.82119}, {315., 0.81193}, {316., 0.80287}, {317., 0.79377}, {318., 
      0.78453}, {319., 0.77542}, {320., 0.76659}, {321., 0.75783}, {322., 
      0.74902}, {323., 0.74036}, {324., 0.73211}, {325., 0.72417}, {326., 
      0.71666}, {327., 0.70927}, {328., 0.70162}, {329., 0.69383}, {330., 
      0.68607}, {331., 0.67845}, {332., 0.67127}, {333., 0.66448}, {334., 
      0.65796}};

EHN[T_] := E\[Infinity] + (E0 - E\[Infinity])/(1 + (I \[Omega] 10^(-((C1 (T - T0))/(C2 + (T - T0)))))^\[Alpha])^\[Beta];
     fitRe=FindFit[dataRe,Re[EHN[T]],{{\[Alpha], 0.2}, {\[Beta], 0.6}, {E0, 4}, {E\[Infinity], 8000}, {C1, 
          17}, {C2, 50}, {\[Omega], 10}}, {T}}];
    fitIm=FindFit[dataIm,Im[EHN[T]],{{\[Alpha], 0.2}, {\[Beta], 0.6}, {E0, 4}, {E\[Infinity], 8000}, {C1, 
          17}, {C2, 50}, {\[Omega], 10}}, {T}}];
    Show[ListPlot[dataRe, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[Re[EHN[T]] /. {fitRe}, {T, 1, 200}]]
    Show[ListPlot[dataIm, PlotStyle -> Orange], Plot[Im[EHN[T]] /. {fitIm}, {T, 1, 250}]]
```

---

However,I cannot fit the Real part and the Imaginary part well.Here is one of my fitted picture:
[image]

Is there any method,which I can fit both the Re and Im part. Thanks.

Comment: There are gaps in your code, brackets missing and there is no initial value for `T0`.

Comment: I'm so sorry. T0(or Tg) is 146

Comment: Ok，thanks. I just find that Tg=146 maybe incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {#, {#2, #4}} & @@@ Join[dataRe, dataIm, 2];
```

Ok, maybe I'm missing something but it seems there is no built in function to fit complex 
functions. So we have to create one:

```
model[T_, E∞_, E0_, ω_, C1_, T0_, C2_, α_, β_] := E∞ + (E0 - 
  E∞)/(1 + (I ω 10^(-((C1 (T - T0))/(C2 + (T - T0)))))^α)^β;

sol = FindMinimum[
       Norm[Flatten[
        ({Re[#], Im[#]} &[model[#, E∞, E0, ω, C1, T0, C2, α, β]] - #2) & @@@ data
       ]],
      {{α, 0.2}, {β, 0.6}, {E0, 4}, {E∞, 8000}, {C1, 17}, {C2, 50}, {ω, 10}, {T0, 110}}]
```

> ```
> {122.628, {α -> 0.303236, β -> 9.03512, E0 -> 10.3146, E∞ -> 7999.98, C1 -> 21.383,
>    C2 -> 36.8504, ω -> 9.93816, T0 -> 121.931}}
> ```

```
With[{opt = Sequence[PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
                     PlotStyle -> Thick, BaseStyle -> PointSize@.01]},
 Row[{
   Plot[Re@model[x, E∞, E0, ω, C1, T0, C2, α, β] /. sol[[2]], {x, 130, 335}, 
        Epilog -> {Point[dataRe]}, opt, PlotLabel -> "Re part"],
   Plot[Im@model[x, E∞, E0, ω, C1, T0, C2, α, β] /. sol[[2]], {x, 130, 335}, 
    Epilog -> {Point[dataIm]}, opt, PlotLabel -> "Im Part"]
   }]]
```

[image]

It is not perfect but this is the way. Try adjust initial values for example.

Comment: I'm a freshman and I cannot read you code. I just copy the code and cannot get the result.Could you give me more details.

Comment: I got this:FindMinimum::nrnum: "函数值 \[Sqrt](Abs[-887.339+Im[(7000. +Times[<<2>>])[135.,7000.,10.,10.,17.,120.,50.,0.3,9.]]]^2+Abs[-797.248+Im[(7000. +Times[<<2>>])[136.,7000.,10.,10.,17.,120.,50.,0.3,9.]]]^2+<<48>>+<<350>>) 不是位于 {\[Alpha],\[Beta],E0,E\[Infinity],C1,C2,\[Omega],T0} = {0.3,9.,10.,7000.,17.,50.,10.,120.} 的一个实数. "

Comment: @YuuhsingTuan Hello again, what the code does is calculating a vector: `{Re@model(x_i), Im@model(x_i)}-data(x_i)`. Then we've got `{{dRe1, dIm1}, {dRe2, dIm2}...}`. Next `Flatten and Norm` produces: `Sqrt[dRe1^2 + dIm1^2 + dRe^2 +...]` and such expression is minimalzed with `FindMinimum`. It isn't the best, usually what is minimalized (LSQ) is `D1^2 + D2^2...`, you can modify. This shouldn't affect much. What can however, is changing initial values and/or model. It simply doesnt look like it can fit both now. You can also perform those procedures for model and data after taking double `Log`.

Comment: your second picture should be “point［dataIm］”.And then the result is very good.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YuuhsingTuan Ha, right :D so it does fit :) Thanks. Nonetheless my comments are still valid for the future ;) Good luck.

Comment: Careful, Set your PlotRange to {0,60} and you'll note that this fit is about the same as mine.

Comment: @bobthechemist Hi :) yes I agree, earlier there was the shift that looked terrible, that's why I'm happy now :P. imo to get a good fit one have to do this on double log data and model. To many parameters now and too high powers.

Comment: I agree, and I figured you knew that.  Just needed to go down on record for the OP since the different scale on my solution makes it "look bad".

Answer (score 5):

The model you are using in your code is missing a T0 which is shown in your question.  I don't know why you would have arbitrarily dropped the parameter, but I have answered this question assuming that you know what you are doing.  Using the approach described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28527/7167) you can model the Real and Imaginary parts simultaneously with using [`NonlinearModelfit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelfit.html):

```
model[T_, E∞_, E0_, ω_, C1_, T0_, C2_, α_, β_][part_] := Module[{f},
   f = If[part == 1, Re, Im];
   f[E∞ + (E0 - E∞)/(1 + 
     (I ω  10^(-((C1 (T - T0))/(C2 + (T - T0)))))^α)^β]];

data = Join[ {#[[1]], 1, #[[2]]} & /@ dataRe, {#[[1]], 0, #[[2]]} & /@
     dataIm];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  model[T, E∞, E0, ω, C1, T0, C2, α, β][
   part], {{α, 0.2}, {β, 0.6}, {E0, 4}, {E∞, 
    8000}, {C1, 17}, {C2, 50}, {ω, 10}, {T0, 110}}, {T, part}]

nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {α -> 0.325145, β -> 4.0862, E0 -> 7.3715, E∞ -> 6021.86, C1 -> 16.1477, 
    C2 -> 26.291, ω -> 40.0271, T0 -> 125.429} *)
```

You do not get a terribly good fit with the initial parameters:

```
Plot[model[T, E∞, E0, ω, C1, T0, 
    C2, α, β][1] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"], {T, 130, 
  335}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], 
   Point /@ Take[data, Length[data]/2][[All, {1, 3}]]}]
Plot[model[T, E∞, E0, ω, C1, T0, 
    C2, α, β][2] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"], {T, 130, 
  335}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], 
   Point /@ Drop[data, Length[data]/2][[All, {1, 3}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking at the correlation matrix, we see that T0, ω, C1 and C2 are very strongly correlated, suggesting that you need to have very good initial estimates for these parameters, or better yet, you need to simplify your model.

```
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your suggest about the model，but I could not change it.May be I can do something for the  initials.

Comment: @YuuhsingTuan see my comment in Kuba's answer.  The problem here is one of y-axis scale.

Comment: oa，I find it.Thanks a lot.But both of your results are better than mine.╯▂╰.And the Im/Re result is not fitted well.(๑´ω`๑)