# Minimize the sum-of-squares errors for a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimizing the sum of squared errors on a 2-equation system of ODEs and empirical data. I keep getting an error and I think the root of the problem is my invocation of `ReplaceAll`.

Here is my code:

```
myode1[kp1_, kp2_, θ_] := 
   ParametricNDSolveValue[{
     p1'[t] == 1/HRT (0.2 p1in - p1[t]) - kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t],
     p2'[t] == 1/HRT (0.8 p1in - p2[t]) - kp2*Exp[θ (temp - 20)]  p2[t] + 
       kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t],
     p1[0] == 0.2 p1in, p2[0] == 0.8 p1in}, 
     {p1, p2}, {t, 0, 350}, {kp1, kp2, θ}];

sumsquare1[kp1_?NumericQ, kp2_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] := 
  Sqrt[Sum[(effpartdata[[i]] - p2[t] /. myode1[kp1, kp2, θ] /. 
    {t -> rtnTime[[i]], temp -> tempCdata[[i]], HRT -> HRTdata[[i]], 
     p1in -> totalCODin[[i]]})^2, {i, 1, 25}]] // Quiet

fitter = NMinimize[sumsquare1[kp1, kp2, θ], {kp1, kp2, θ}]
```

The arrays: `HRTdata`, `totalCODin`, `tempCdata`, `effpartdata` and `rtnTime` are my data arrays. Added them below. I've seen a couple other data fitting questions (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/how-to-fit-parameters-in-a-system-of-coupled-differential-equations?rq=1) & [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations/28527#28527)), but mine differs in that I have multiple data trails and as of right now I've been unable to tweak the other codes to accomodate that.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Tried using `ParametricNDSolveValue` and calling `Quiet` on my `sumsquare1` function to no avail. thanks @Guess who it is

```
partDATA1 = {{1.`, 1.`, 8.88889`, 2652.`, 156.`, 261.`, 59.`, 2391.`, 97.`, 0.959`}, {1.`, 1.`, 8.889`, 2652.`, 170.`, 261.`, 51.`, 2391.`, 119.`, 0.950`}, {0.5`, 0.166`, 12.88`, 2544.`, 663.`, 493.`, 317.`, 2051.`, 346.`, 0.831`}, {1.`, 1.`, 7.22`, 2014.`, 100.`, 134.`, 32.`, 1880.`, 68.`, 0.963`}, {1.`, 1.`, 13.166`, 1902.`, 66.`, 116.`, 8.`, 1786.`, 58.`, 0.967`}, {1.`, 1.`, 13.166`, 1902.`, 48.`, 159.`, 10.`, 1743.`, 38.`, .978`}, {0.5`, 0.166`, 11.66`, 1964.`, 349.`, 224.`, 134.`, 1740.`, 215.`, 0.8764367816091954`}, {0.5`, 0.166`, 14.722`, 1568.`, 406.`, 203.`, 147.`, 1365.`, 259.`, 0.81`}, {0.5`, 0.166`, 14.722`, 1568.`, 406.`, 203.`, 143.`, 1365.`, 263.`, 0.8073260073260073`}, {1.`, 1.`, 6.833333333333332`, 1434.`, 92.`, 163.`, 62.`, 1271.`, 30.`, 0.97639653815893`}, {1.`, 1.`, 6.833333333333332`, 1434.`, 110.`, 163.`, 58.`, 1271.`, 52.`, 0.959087332808812`}, {1.`, 1.`, 7.000000000000001`, 1073.`, 150.`, 150.`, 70.`, 923.`, 80.`, 0.9133261105092091`}, {1.`, 1.`, 7.000000000000001`, 1073.`, 116.`, 150.`, 74.`, 923.`, 42.`, 0.9544962080173348`}, {1.`, 0.166`, 15.55`, 932.`, 361.`, 202.`, 138.`, 730.`, 223.`, 0.694`}, {1.`, 1.`, 7722`, 937.`, 78.`, 273.`, 71.`, 664.`, 7.`, 0.9892`}, {1.`, 1.`, 7.22`, 937.`, 97.`, 273.`, 65.`, 664.`, 32.`, 0.951`}, {1.`, 1.`, 13.333`, 479.`, 132.`, 116.`, 48.`, 363.`, 84.`, 0.768`}, {1.`, 0.66`, 20.557`, 670.`, 150.`, 310.`, 74.`, 360.`, 76.`, 0.88`}, {0.5`, 0.166`, 12.8`, 663.`, 306.`, 317.`, 233.`, 346.`, 73.`, 0.789`}, {1.`, 0.33`, 19.33`, 500.`, 200.`, 234.`, 117.`, 266.`, 83.`,0.687`}, {0.5`, 0.66`, 14.22`, 406.`, 196.`, 143.`, 92.`, 263.`, 104.`,0.604`}, {0.5`, 0.166`, 14.22`, 406.`, 271.`, 147.`, 102.`, 259.`, 169.`,0.3474`}, {1.`, 0.66`, 20.55`, 328.`, 148.`, 124.`, 64.`, 204.`, 84.`,0.58`}, {1.`, 1.`, 13.05`, 391.`, 75.`,230.`, 105.`, 161.`, 10.`, 0.937`}, {1.`,0.33`, 19.33`, 244.`, 122.`, 234.`,120.`, 10.`, 2.`, 0.8`}};
HRTdata = partDATA1[[All, 1]];
totalCODin = partDATA1[[All, 4]];
tempCdata = partDATA1[[All, 3]];
effpartdata = partDATA1[[All, 9]];
rtnTime = partDATA1[[All, 2]];
```

Comment: The new function `ParametricNDSolve[]` seems to be useful for this situation.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I gave `ParametricNDSolve[]` a go with no success. the error is coming up when I use `NMinimize` or `FindMinimum`. I suspect it is because of All the parameters I am trying to `/.` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit notice: It turns out the system can be integrated exactly, which leads to faster performance.]

### Using `DSolve`

I replaced the approximate coefficients `0.2` and `0.8` by the exact numbers `2/10` and `8/10`; otherwise, things that should cancel out do not and lead to false singularities.

```
myode1 = Function[{kp1, kp2, θ, temp, HRT, p1in}, 
   Evaluate@
    First@DSolve[{p1'[t] == 
        1/HRT (2/10 p1in - p1[t]) - kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t], 
       p2'[t] == 
        1/HRT (8/10 p1in - p2[t]) - kp2*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p2[t] + 
         kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t],
       p1[0] == 2/10 p1in, p2[0] == 8/10 p1in}, {p1, p2}, t]];

Clear[sumsquare1C];
sumsquare1[kp1_, kp2_, θ_] =
  Sqrt[Sum[(effpartdata[[i]] - p2[t] /. 
        myode1[kp1, kp2, θ, tempCdata[[i]], HRTdata[[i]], 
         totalCODin[[i]]] /. t -> rtnTime[[i]])^2, {i, 1, 
     Length[rtnTime]}]];

fitter = NMinimize[{sumsquare1C[kp1, kp2, θ],
    {0 < kp1 < 25, 1 < kp2 < 10, 0.1 < θ < 4}}, {kp1, kp2, θ}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {3.53719, {1289.68, {kp1 -> 0., kp2 -> 10., θ -> 0.1}}}
*)
```

#### Original answer

Use `ParametricNDSolve` instead of `ParametricNDSolveValue`. It returns replacement rules for replacing `p1` and `p2` by their corresponding `ParametricFunction`. Note the arguments to a `ParametricFunction` are the parameters and you do not need them to be arguments to `myode1`.

There are parameters `HRT`, `temp`, and `p1in` that are not declared as parameters for `ParametricNDSolve`, but they should be.

```
myode1 = ParametricNDSolve[
   {p1'[t] == 1/HRT (0.2 p1in - p1[t]) - kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t], 
    p2'[t] == 1/HRT (0.8 p1in - p2[t]) - kp2*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p2[t] + 
      kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t],
    p1[0] == 0.2 p1in, p2[0] == 0.8 p1in},
   {p1, p2}, {t, 0, 350}, {kp1, kp2, θ, temp, HRT, p1in}];

sumsquare1[kp1_?NumericQ, kp2_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[Sum[
   (effpartdata[[i]] -
       p2[kp1, kp2, θ, tempCdata[[i]], HRTdata[[i]], totalCODin[[i]]][t] /.
     myode1 /. t -> rtnTime[[i]])^2,
   {i, 1, 9}]]
fitter = NMinimize[
  sumsquare1[kp1, kp2, θ], {kp1, kp2, θ}, 
  Method -> {"NelderMead", 
    "InitialPoints" -> {{0, 1, -0.1}, {1, 0, -0.1}, {0.1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -1}}}]
(*
  {72.1155, {kp1 -> -0.2426, kp2 -> 9.28932, \[Theta] -> -0.0641051}}
*)
```

I get some `ParametricNDSolve::mxst` errors that may be of concern.  Perhaps the initial points are not well chosen.  I'll leave that to the OP.

Comment: As always-Thank you so much! Your guys' help goes farther than you know. If you don't mind, can you elaborate on your use of `ParametricNDSolve` instead of `ParametricNDSolveValue`? And is that the reason why @DanielLichtblau 's response runs So Much faster than the above? Or is it because of the algorithmic differences in the function `sumsquare1`?

Comment: @e3labs Which one is faster?  I found my `sumsquare1` about 4 times faster. What was your input exactly?

Comment: Daniel's is faster. I used exactly what you had there. Except my dataset has a length of 25 (updated in OP). And I added a constraint on NMinimize: 10<kp1<25, `1<kp2<10, 0.1<theta<4`. BTW I tried using {i,1,1} instead of 25 (or 9) and it took about 10 seconds to run. Could it be because it cycles through all of the data points?

Comment: @e3labs `Table[sumsquare1[kp1, kp2, theta], {kp1, 0, 25}, {kp2, 1, 10}, {theta, 0.1`, 4}]; // AbsoluteTiming` takes 4.5 ± 0.2 sec with my definition and 23-24 sec with Daniel's -- I have no idea why, though.  The length `Length[rtnTime]` is 9, so I can't test 25.  Comparing values, there are some slight differences (mainly less than `10^-12` but some as high as `6*10^-10`.  It could be than minimizing a numerical approximation is sensitive to such slight oscillations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one variant that seems to evaluate to a number.

```
myode1[p1in_?NumericQ, HRT_?NumericQ, temp_?NumericQ] := 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{p1'[t] == 
     1/HRT (0.2 p1in - p1[t]) - kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t], 
    p2'[t] == 
     1/HRT (0.8 p1in - p2[t]) - kp2*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p2[t] + 
      kp1*Exp[θ (temp - 20)] p1[t], p1[0] == 0.2 p1in, 
    p2[0] == 0.8 p1in}, {p1[t], p2[t]}, {t, 0, 350}, {kp1, 
    kp2, θ}];

sumsquare1[kp1_?NumericQ, kp2_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[Total @
   Table[(effpartdata[[i]] - (With[{temp = tempCdata[[i]], 
           HRT = HRTdata[[i]], p1in = totalCODin[[i]]}, 
          myode1[p1in, HRT, temp][kp1, kp2, θ][[2]]] /. {t -> 
           rtnTime[[i]]}))^2, {i, 1, Length[rtnTime]}]]
```