# How do I fit experimental data by solving 3 coupled ODEs with adjustable parameters?

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

I want to fit experimental data by solving 3 coupled differential equations.The ODEs are rate equations modeling the dynamics of hot carriers in semiconductors after excitation. The function use fot fitting data is x2 and the parameters are *ntrmax, trec* and *tc*. I was inspired by comments from [Peng Bai](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/how-to-fit-parameters-in-a-system-of-coupled-differential-equations) when writting the following code but It does not work and I can't figure out why yet.

```
P[t_]= 4.9560 * 10^18 Exp[-1732.87 t^2];

 Nphoton = 2.1102 * 10^17;
tr = 0.2;

data = {{{0., 0., -0.000367822, 0., 0.000435918}, {0.1334, 0.01008,0.0000753379, -0.000200166, -0.000520431},{0.267,0.02302,-0.000766664,-0.000244647,-0.000209062},{0.4004,0.03347, 0.00207, 0.00133,-0.0000533769},{0.5338,0.06225,0.00772, 0.00654, 0.00186},{0.6672, 0.07971, 0.01499, 0.01052,0.00362}, {0.8006, 0.07766, 0.0196, 0.01717, 0.00522},{0.934,0.07577, 0.03668, 0.02662, 0.00975}, {1.0674, 0.07153, 0.03945,0.02604,0.01389},{1.2008,0.0715,0.03943,0.02398,0.01189}, {1.3344, 0.06899,0.03748,0.02269,0.01147},{1.4678,0.06541, 0.03571, 0.02017, 0.01113},{1.6012,0.06087,0.03342, 0.01928, 0.01104},{1.7346, 0.06103, 0.03238, 0.01886, 0.01029}, {1.868, 0.06061, 0.02904, 0.0179, 0.00922},{2.0014,0.05896, 0.02939, 0.01806, 0.00771}, {2.1348, 0.05629, 0.0285,0.01657, 0.00849},{2.2684,0.05387, 0.02817,0.01579,0.00782}, {2.4018, 0.05418, 0.02622, 0.0157, 0.00693}, {2.5352,0.05342,0.02558,0.01506,0.00633},{2.6686, 0.05169, 0.0235,0.01417, 0.00626}, {2.802, 0.04953, 0.02494,0.01348,0.00568},{2.9354,0.04977,0.02392, 0.01312, 0.00528},{3.0688, 0.04788, 0.02347, 0.01241, 0.00573},{3.2022, 0.04753, 0.02294,0.01152,0.00609},{3.3358, 0.04713, 0.02148, 0.01212,0.00488},{3.4692, 0.04553, 0.0213, 0.01136, 0.00504},{3.6026,0.04461, 0.02146, 0.01079,0.00504},{3.736, 0.04348, 0.02108,0.01025, 0.00455},{3.8694, 0.04279,0.01969, 0.01021,0.00419},{4.0028, 0.04337, 0.01864, 0.01021,0.00522},{4.1362,0.04321, 0.01913, 0.01003, 0.00466},{4.2696,0.04168, 0.01842,0.00914, 0.00448},{4.4032, 0.0395, 0.01758, 0.00952,0.00442},{4.5366,0.03814, 0.01689, 0.00843, 0.00399},{4.67,0.0403, 0.01647, 0.00854,0.00391}, {4.8034, 0.03894, 0.01654,0.0083, 0.00364},{4.9368,0.03865, 0.01654, 0.0091,0.00397},{5.0702, 0.03732, 0.0168, 0.00896, 0.00233},{5.2036, 0.03672, 0.01696, 0.00812, 0.00364},{5.337, 0.0359, 0.01592, 0.00825, 0.00344},{5.4706, 0.03541, 0.01621, 0.00823, 0.00322},{5.604, 0.03381, 0.0157, 0.0083, 0.00397},{5.7374, 0.03472, 0.01514, 0.00747, 0.00275},{5.8708, 0.03456, 0.01525,0.00754, 0.00368},{6.0042, 0.03414, 0.01454,0.00705,0.00342},{6.1376, 0.03198, 0.01472, 0.00656, 0.00266},{6.271,0.03209, 0.01421, 0.00705, 0.00326},{6.4044, 0.03245, 0.01355,0.0079,0.00315},{6.538, 0.0312, 0.01386, 0.00696, 0.00295},{6.6714, 0.03103, 0.01377, 0.00623, 0.00213},{6.8048, 0.03118, 0.01304, 0.00643, 0.00264},{6.9382, 0.03016, 0.01135, 0.00718, 0.00262},{7.0716, 0.02962,0.01189, 0.00718, 0.00159},{7.205, 0.02998, 0.01189, 0.00585, 0.00244},{7.3384, 0.02956, 0.01171, 0.00607, 0.00226},{7.472, 0.02885, 0.01246,0.00621, 0.00233},{7.6054, 0.02869, 0.01235, 0.00616,0.00239}, {7.7388, 0.02882, 0.01162, 0.00614, 0.00235},{7.8722, 0.02831,0.01233,0.00583, 0.00255}, {8.0056, 0.02664, 0.01111,0.00634,0.0027}, {8.139, 0.02747, 0.01038, 0.00518,0.00295}, {8.2724, 0.0262, 0.0106, 0.00589,0.00264}, {8.4058,0.02662, 0.01009, 0.00547, 0.00226}, {8.5394,0.0256, 0.00947, 0.00527, 0.00206}, {8.6728, 0.02524, 0.0102,0.00467,0.00206}, {8.8062, 0.02415, 0.00971, 0.00458, 0.00197}, {8.9396,0.02302, 0.00945, 0.00434, 0.0019}, {9.073, 0.02382, 0.00969, 0.005, 0.0021}, {9.2064, 0.02346, 0.00989, 0.00527,0.00175}, {9.3398, 0.02289, 0.00967, 0.00483, 0.00179}, {9.4732,0.02226, 0.01007, 0.00527, 0.00177}, {9.6068, 0.02291, 0.00925, 0.00451, 0.00133}, {9.7402, 0.02264, 0.00985, 0.0052,0.00204}, {9.8722, 0.02362, 0.00909, 0.00405, 0.00104}, {10.007,0.0226, 0.00954, 0.00451, 0.0013}, {10.1404, 0.02137, 0.00907,0.0044, 0.00199}, {10.2738, 0.02186, 0.00958, 0.00451, 0.00195}}}

ti = data[[1, All, 1]];
ci = Nphoton*data[[1, All, 2 ;; 5]];

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x1'[t] == P[t] - x1[t]/tr,x2'[t] == x1[t]/tr - x2[t] (1 - (x3[t]/ntrmax))/tp - x2[t]/trec, x3'[t] == x2[t] (1 - (x3[t]/ntrmax))/tp - x3[t]/trec, x1[0] == P[0], x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 0}, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, 20}, {ntrmax, trec, tp}];(*three dependent variables*)

 f[ntrmax_?NumericQ, trec_?NumericQ, tp_?NumericQ] := Sum[Total[(ci[[All, i]] - Map[pfun[ntrmax, trec, tp][[i]], ti])^2], {i, 1, 4}] // Quiet;

fit = NMinimize[f[ntrmax, trec, tp], {ntrmax, trec, tp}];

params = fit // Last
```

Comment: In your definition of `f` your `pfun` only has 3 interpolating functions and you are taking parts `{i, 1, 4}` which gives a string of `"Part 4 of {<<1>>} does not exist"` errors. Changing that 4 to 3 seems to get rid of those errors, but you have another error which may be that you aren't correctly getting a numeric result from `pfun`. Can you track down and correct those? You also have extremely large and extremely small coefficients and only a single digit of precision for `tr`, all of which may make for very uncertain results. Without trying to do the fit, can you get good results from `f`?

Comment: `data` has five columns. What do these columns correspond to among the parameters `t, x1, x2, x3`?

Comment: @BilI I changed the number of interpolating functions to 3 in `pfun` tried to simply the problem by normalizing the `data ci = data[[1,All, 2;;5]]`
and 
`pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x1'[t] == P[t]/P[0] - x1[t]/tr,x2'[t] == x1[t]/tr - x2[t] (1 - (x3[t]/ntrmax))/tp - x2[t]/trec, x3'[t] == x2[t] (1 - (x3[t]/ntrmax))/tp - x3[t]/trec, x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 0}, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, 20}, {ntrmax, trec, tp}];` 
Computed parameters do not converge to experimental data.

Comment: The first column (left) in data refers to independent variables and three columns correspond to dependent variables.