# How do I get the MeanPredictionBands from the fitting of the numerical solution of coupled differential equations to data?

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics, fitting, chemistry

This is my first post, and I will preface my question by stating that I am relatively new to *Mathematica*.

In any case, I would like to fit the solution of chemical kinetics equations to data and get the resulting `"MeanPredictionBands"`.  Using the [answer to a previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations) as a starting point, I am able to fit a very simple set of chemical kinetics equations to two data sets self-consistently (see example code below).

```
tmax = 100.; (*region of time in which we are interested to have a \
solution*)

(*Define a simple chemical kinetics coupled differential equation*)
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {D[s1[t], t] == k1 s1[t] s2[t],
   D[s2[t], t] == -k1 s1[t] s2[t],
   s1[0] == 0.1,
   s2[0] == 10.},

  {s1, s2},

  {t, 0, tmax},

  {k1}
  ];

(*temp variables that help us avoid solving the coupled differential \
equations over and over if "model" is called without changing k1temp*)


k1temp = 0.1;
soltemp = sol[k1temp];

(*the function definition that will return the solution of the \
coupled differential equations for a given k1, species and time*)
model[k1_?NumericQ][species_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] :=
  Module[{returnval, intspecies},
   If[k1 != k1temp,
    soltemp = sol[k1];
    k1temp = k1;
    ];
   intspecies = Round[species];
   soltemp[[intspecies]][t]
   ];

(*Make some fake data using model*)
data = {};
Do[
  Do[
   noise = RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}];
   AppendTo[data, {i, t, model[0.2][i, t] + noise}];
   , {t, 0., tmax/10.}]
  , {i, 1, 2}];

(*fit the fake data*)
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k1f][i, t], {{k1f, 0.3}}, {i, t}];

fit["ParameterTable"]
```

Using the `FittedModel` from `NonlinearModelFit`, I expected it to be straight forward to get the `"MeanPredictionBands"` via the following function definition.

```
meanpredictionbandsfunc[i_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] = 
 fit["MeanPredictionBands"]
```

This function definition, however, is giving me a number of warnings/errors and when evaluated it does not give me the `"MeanPredictionBands"` as I would expect.  For example, the evaluation

```
meanpredictionbandsfunc[1, 10]
```

is giving me the following errors

```
StringForm::sfr: Item 2 requested in "`1` cannot be interpreted. The operator `2` requires a subscript with a variable specification." out of range; 1 items available.

Internal`LocalizedBlock::novar: 1 cannot be interpreted. The operator `2` requires a subscript with a variable specification.

StringForm::sfr: Item 2 requested in "`1` cannot be interpreted. The operator `2` requires a subscript with a variable specification." out of range; 1 items available.

Internal`LocalizedBlock::novar: 1 cannot be interpreted. The operator `2` requires a subscript with a variable specification.

StringForm::sfr: Item 2 requested in "`1` cannot be interpreted. The operator `2` requires a subscript with a variable specification." out of range; 1 items available.

Internal`LocalizedBlock::novar: 1 cannot be interpreted. The operator `2` requires a subscript with a variable specification.
```

How should I define a function to provide me with the `"MeanPredictionBands"`?

I would really appreciate your help/suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

In this case because your model is not simple (in that it contains `If` statements and interpolating functions) both `MeanPredictionBands` and `SinglePredictionBands` don't work.  (I think that use of functions like `Abs` in the model also makes `MeanPredictionBands` not work - but I could be wrong about that.)

I've removed the `If` statements from your model but I think it works identically as before:

```
model[k1_?NumericQ, species_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := sol[k1][[species]][t];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k1f, i, t], {{k1f, 0.3}}, {i, t}];
```

There are two things one can do.  First, the values of the `MeanPredictionBands` can be obtained for the individual observations using `MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals`:

```
fit["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"]
(* {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.627004, 0.705878}, {3.07832, 3.64677}, {7.53791, 8.1988},
 {9.61518, 9.80514}, {10.0249, 10.0609}, {10.0888, 10.095}, {10.0983, 10.0994},
 {10.0998, 10.0999}, {10.1, 10.1}, {10.1, 10.1}, {10., 10.}, {9.39412, 9.473},
 {6.45323, 7.02168}, {1.9012, 2.56209}, {0.294855, 0.484816}, {0.0390947,  0.0750506},
 {0.00503452, 0.0112016}, {0.000639995, 0.00165984}, {0.0000802901,  0.000245284},
 {9.9049*10^-6,  0.0000361818}, {1.19425*10^-6, 5.32897*10^-6}} *)
```

The other thing to do is to construct the confidence bands directly using the `CovarianceMatrix` and the *Delta Method*.  For your example you only have one parameter so you can find the lower and upper bands just by plugging in the lower and upper confidence limits for `k1f`:

```
k1mle = k1f /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
{k1lower, k1upper} = fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervals"][[1]]

Show[ListPlot[data[[All, {2, 3}]]],
 Plot[{model[k1mle, 1, t], model[k1lower, 1, t], model[k1upper, 1, t]}, 
   {t, 0, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Green}],
 Plot[{model[k1mle, 2, t], model[k1lower, 2, t], model[k1upper, 2, t]},
   {t, 0, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Green}]]
```

[image: Confidence bands]

There are two bands because you have different curves depending on species.

Comment: The “Delta Method” is straight forward for this 1-parameter, simple example I provided above, but what I really need is a solution when there are 5-10 parameters.  Though, I admit, that the “Delta Method” can probably be applied in this case as well, though it will certainly not be this straight forward.

Comment: I don’t think the “If” statements need to be removed if you want to use fit[“MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals”].  Removing the “If” statements from the definition of "model", as you propose, results in the same value, but can be very slow when used in "Plot[]", especially when it takes a long time (i.e. minutes or more) to solve "sol" since “sol” is evaluated for each point in time and really only needs to be evaluated once for a given set of parameters.