# Chemical Kinetics: fitting multiple sets of time series data using multiple differential reaction equations

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, chemistry

Let me start by saying that this is my first post, so if there are suggestions on proper formatting that is annoying you, please let fly and I will do my best to modify.

I was doing well solving the topic in the title until I attempted to model second order reactions, which seemed to "break" *Mathematica*. I'll use an example of analogous code to get my point across.

So first I define my time series data as follows, including initial concentrations:

```
data = {{0., 182.115, 0.}, {1., 166.486, 1.87153}, {5., 136.178, 
   9.76618}, {10., 112.277, 19.1688}, {15., 111.448, 27.2978}, {25., 
   81.5446, 43.3609}, {35., 73.6962, 56.2542}, {45., 62.9892, 
   62.6874}, {55., 50.7161, 68.5274}, {65., 45.2139, 79.0054}};

{time, Xylose, Furfural} = Transpose[data];

Fin = Furfural[[1]];

Xin = Xylose[[1]];
```

Then I set up the various rate equations for the chemical species, and solve for the rate constants; so far, this is all well and good, and the output can be seen below.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == -a X[t] - b X[t], X[0] == Xin, 
    F'[t] == a X[t] - c F[t], F[0] == Fin}, {X, F}, {t, 0, 70}, {a, b,
     c}];

transformeddata = {ConstantArray[Range@Length[{Xylose, Furfural}], 
      Length[time]] // Transpose, 
    ConstantArray[time, Length[{Xylose, Furfural}]], {Xylose, 
     Furfural}}~Flatten~{{2, 3}, {1}};

model[a_, b_, c_][i_, t_] := 
  Through[sol[a, b, c][t], List][[i]] /; 
   And @@ NumericQ /@ {a, b, c, i, t};

fit = NonlinearModelFit[transformeddata, 
   model[a, b, c][i, t], {a, b, c}, {i, t}];

fit["RSquared"]

fit["ParameterTable"]

Show[ListPlot[Table[Take[data, All, {1, l, l - 1}], {l, 2, 3}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]], 
 Plot[{fit[1, t], fit[2, t]}, {t, 0, 70}]]
```

(*This works great for modeling first order reaction kinetics*)

The "`Show` stopper" comes when I try to represent a reaction with second order kinetics; all the above are first order kinetics. So for instance when I change the following:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == **-a X[t]** - b X[t], X[0] == Xin, 
    F'[t] == **a X[t]** - c F[t], F[0] == Fin}, {X, F}, {t, 0, 70}, {a, b,
     c}];
```

into

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == **-a X[t] X[t]** - b X[t], X[0] == Xin, 
    F'[t] == **a X[t] X[t]** - c F[t], F[0] == Fin}, {X, F}, {t, 0, 70}, {a, b,
     c}];
```

then the output I get has the following errors:

[image: Unsuccessful run with second order kinetics]

In short, I'm not sure why this solve function is having trouble with representing second order reactions in this way. Any advice or information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28461/7167) to see if the method provides any help to you.

Comment: @bobthechemist meets @RobtheChemist?!

Comment: @Chris, it was fated...

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide starting values for `NonlinearModelFit`.

First, I took your `model` and played with its parameters untill it *looked good*:

```
Show[Plot[model[0., 0.03, 0][1, t], {t, 0, 70}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot@Transpose@{time, Xylose}]
```

[image]

(You could wrap it in `Manipulate`.) It's very sensitive to the values of `a`, moderately sensitive to `b` and unnoticeably sensitive to `c`.

Next, I used those parameters as starting values (no errors at all):

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[transformeddata, 
   model[a, b, c][i, t], {{a, 0.}, {b, 0.03}, {c, 0}}, {i, t}];

fit["RSquared"]
```

> 0.991887

```
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[Table[Take[data, All, {1, l, l - 1}], {l, 2, 3}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]], 
 Plot[{fit[1, t], fit[2, t]}, {t, 0, 70}]]
```

[image]

Comment: in this example, how can we define that the parameter should have positive value?