# Fitting delay differential equations (DDE)

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, fitting, nonlinear, modeling

I have the following differential equations:

$$S'(t) = 0.31 S(t) \Big( 1 - \frac{S(t)}{6.19} \Big)- \frac{a}{1 + B(t)} S(t),$$

$$B'(t) = c (1 - B(t)) - d B(t) S(t) - 3 c (1 - B(t - 18)),$$
where $B(t - 18)$ changes the ODE to DDE, and the constants $a$, $c$, and $d$ should be determined from the data sets:

```
Sdata = {{0, 0.974},{3, 0.492},{6, 0.829},{9, 0.554},{15, 0.208},{18, 0.138},{21, 0.199},{24, 0.0893}};

Bdata = {{0, 0.915094},{3, 0.736097},{6, 0.793694},{9, 0.833664},{15, 1},{18, 0.99578},{21, 0.897964},{24, 0.214499}};
```

Also the the standard deviations of the data are given:

```
SdatawithSD = {{0, Around[0.974, 0.289]}, {3, Around[0.492, 0.165]}, {6, Around[0.829, 0.404]}, {9, Around[0.554, 0.245]}, {15, Around[0.208, 0.191]}, {18, Around[0.138, 0.0962]}, {21, Around[0.199, 0.241]}, {24, Around[0.0893, 0.0359]}};

BdatawithSD = {{0, Around[0.915094, 0.1]}, {3, Around[0.736097, 0.091668]}, {6, Around[0.793694, 0.082575]}, {9, Around[0.833664, 0.070242]}, {15, Around[1, 0.002851]}, {18, Around[0.99578, 0.015591]}, {21, Around[0.897964, 0.04783]}, {24, Around[0.214499, 0.01231]}};
```

First, let us guess our parameters and see how the results look like:

```
s = NDSolve[{ss'[t] + 0.9/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, bb'[t] - 0.3 (1 - bb[t]) + 0.37 bb[t] ss[t] + 0.9 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0, 
ss[t /; t < 0] == 1.05, bb[t /; t < 0] == 1.01}, {ss, bb}, {t, 0, 24}];

gr05 = Plot[Evaluate[bb[t] /. s], {t, 0, 24}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}];

gr07 = Plot[Evaluate[ss[t] /. s], {t, 0, 24}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}];

g11 = ListPlot[BdatawithSD, PlotStyle -> {Orange, PointSize[0.02]}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}];
g22 = ListPlot[SdatawithSD, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}];

Show[g11, gr05, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "B(t)"}, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 18, GrayLevel[0]}, ImageSize -> Large]

Show[g22, gr07, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "S(t)"}, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 18, GrayLevel[0]}, 
ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

So, our guesses were not that much bad, and we can take these parameters' values as a hint for fitting.

Now, for fitting, one can write (I have adopted the code from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4814331/1261034), which works fine for non-delay differential equations):

```
fitness[a00_?NumberQ, c00_?NumberQ, d00_?NumberQ, s0_?NumberQ, b0_?NumberQ] := 
Module[{ss, bb, parms, odes, ODES, solode, cinits, ssbb, t}, 
odes = {ss'[t] + a00/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, 
bb'[t] - c00 (1 - bb[t]) + d00 bb[t] ss[t] + 3 c00 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0};
cinits = {ss[0] == s0, bb[0] == b0};
ODES = Join[odes, cinits];
solode = Quiet@NDSolve[ODES, {ss, bb}, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}][[1]];
Return[Sum[Norm[{y1[[k]], y2[[k]]} - Evaluate[{ss[t], bb[t]} /. solode /. {t -> tk[[k]]}]], {k, 1, 8}]]]

tk = {0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24};
y1 = {0.974, 0.492, 0.829, 0.554, 0.208, 0.138, 0.199, 0.0893};
y2 = {0.915094, 0.736097, 0.793694, 0.833664, 1, 0.99578, 0.897964, 0.214499};

restrs = {0.7 < a00 < 1 && 0.1 < c00 < 0.5 && 0.1 < d00 < 0.5 && 0.9 < s0 < 1.2 && 0.9 < b0 < 1.2};
vars = {a00, c00, d00, s0, b0};

sol = Quiet@FindMinimum[Join[{fitness[a00, c00, d00, s0, b0]}, restrs], {{a00, 0.7}, {c00, 0.1}, {d00, 0.1}, {s0, 0.9}, {b0, 0.9}}, StepMonitor :> 
Print[{a00, c00, d00, s0, b0, fitness[a00, c00, d00, s0, b0]}], MaxIterations -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 90]

odes = {ss'[t] + a00/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, bb'[t] - c00 (1 - bb[t]) + d00 bb[t] ss[t] + 3 c00 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0} /. sol[[2]];
cinits = {ss[0] == s0, bb[0] == b0} /. sol[[2]];
ODES = Join[odes, cinits];
solode = NDSolve[ODES, {ss, bb}, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}][[1]];

gr0 = Plot[Evaluate[ss[t] /. solode], {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}];
gr10 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, y1}], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLabel -> "S(t)"];
gr2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, y2}], PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[gr10, gr0]

gr00 = Plot[Evaluate[bb[t] /. solode], {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}];
gr02 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, y2}], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
PlotLabel -> "B(t)"];
Show[gr02, gr00]
```

The above doesn't produce a decent fit. This code used to work very well for fitting in the case of usual ordinary differential equations, but it seems it doesn't work well enough for DDE. Any help to revise the code or proposing another approach is really appreciated.

Can this code be revised in order to explicitly use `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: It seems that you've asked this question 5 different times with multiple minor edits, and expecting to get a reproducible fit for a complicated function with 3 parameters and just 8 data points.  Is that an inaccurate assessment?  Biological data just doesn't consistently follow theoretical models.  Is there a justification/reference for the structure of the model you've proposed?

Comment: A better forum would be CrossValidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com) for "what to do" and then back here for implementation.  Although explaining the rationale for the model would be essential on that forum.  And you'll certainly still run in to the comment about "3 parameters with only 8 data points."  (And I do understand the issue both not being able to get more data and that even 8 data points can be prohibitively expensive.)

Comment: It's not an issue with overfitting.  If it was overfitting, you'd have a much better fit.  It appears that your data is generated by a process more complicated than the proposed model.

Comment: This is my assessment:  @Cesareo provides a better fit to the data but now with 5 parameters and still just 8 data points.  So I think having confidence in this model is just wishful thinking and without an assessment of the lack of fit error potentially misleading.

Comment: Here are two approaches:  (1) Use `MultiNonlinearModelFit` (as in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293266/using-parametricndsolvevalue-and-multinonlinearmodelfit-to-fit-an-ode-system-to) and (2) Perform simulations where you generate data from the resulting values of the parameters (either from your model or @Cesareo 's model) incorporating the sampling error from your `Around` statements.  From those simulations you can construct confidence intervals for the parameters and the resulting curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing few modifications in the actual script, we found using MATHEMATICA version 12.0.0 running under Linux,

[image]

[image]

Follows the script

```
fitness[a00_?NumberQ, c00_?NumberQ, d00_?NumberQ, s0_?NumberQ, b0_?NumberQ] := Module[{ss, bb, parms, odes, ODES, solode, cinits, ssbb, t}, 
  odes = {ss'[t] + a00/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, bb'[t] - c00 (1 - bb[t]) + d00 bb[t] ss[t] + 3 c00 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0};
  cinits = {ss[t /; t <= 0] == s0, bb[t /; t <= 0] == b0};
  ODES = Join[odes, cinits];
  solode = Quiet@NDSolve[ODES, {ss, bb}, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}][[1]];
  Return[Sum[Norm[{y1[[k]], y2[[k]]} - Evaluate[{ss[t], bb[t]} /. solode /. {t -> tk[[k]]}]], {k, 1, 8}]]]

tk = {0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24};
y1 = {0.974, 0.492, 0.829, 0.554, 0.208, 0.138, 0.199, 0.0893};
y2 = {0.915094, 0.736097, 0.793694, 0.833664, 1, 0.99578, 0.897964, 0.214499};
SdatawithSD = {{0, Around[0.974, 0.289]}, {3, 
Around[0.492, 0.165]}, {6, Around[0.829, 0.404]}, {9, 
Around[0.554, 0.245]}, {15, Around[0.208, 0.191]}, {18, 
Around[0.138, 0.0962]}, {21, Around[0.199, 0.241]}, {24, 
Around[0.0893, 0.0359]}};
BdatawithSD = {{0, Around[0.915094, 0.1]}, {3, 
Around[0.736097, 0.091668]}, {6, Around[0.793694, 0.082575]}, {9, 
Around[0.833664, 0.070242]}, {15, Around[1, 0.002851]}, {18, 
Around[0.99578, 0.015591]}, {21, Around[0.897964, 0.04783]}, {24, 
Around[0.214499, 0.01231]}};


restrs = {0.7 - 0.2 < a00 < 1 + 0.2 && 0.1 < c00 < 0.5 + 0.2 && 0.1 < d00 < 0.5 + 0.2 && 0.9 - 0.2 < s0 < 1.2 + 0.2 && 0.9 - 0.2 < b0 < 1.2 + 0.2};
vars = {a00, c00, d00, s0, b0};

sol = Quiet@NMinimize[Join[{fitness[a00, c00, d00, s0, b0]}, restrs], vars, StepMonitor :> Print[{a00, c00, d00, s0, b0, fitness[a00, c00, d00, s0, b0]}], 
 MaxIterations -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

odes = {ss'[t] + a00/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, 
bb'[t] - c00 (1 - bb[t]) + d00 bb[t] ss[t] + 3 c00 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0} /. sol[[2]];
cinits = {ss[t /; t <= 0] == s0, bb[t /; t <= 0] == b0} /. sol[[2]];
ODES = Join[odes, cinits];
solode = NDSolve[ODES, {ss, bb}, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}][[1]];

g11 = ListPlot[SdatawithSD, PlotStyle -> {Orange, PointSize[0.02]}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}];
gr10 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, y1}], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLabel -> "S(t)"];
gr0 = Plot[Evaluate[ss[t] /. solode], {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}];
Show[g11, gr10, gr0]

g22 = ListPlot[BdatawithSD, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}];
gr2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, y2}], PlotStyle -> Blue];
gr00 = Plot[Evaluate[bb[t] /. solode], {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}];
gr02 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, y2}], PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLabel -> "B(t)"];
Show[g22, gr02, gr00]
```

NOTE

Modifying slightly the `fitness` function to

```
fitness[a00_?NumberQ, c00_?NumberQ, d00_?NumberQ, s0_?NumberQ, b0_?NumberQ] := Module[{ss, bb, parms, odes, ODES, solode, cinits, ssbb, t}, 
  odes = {ss'[t] + a00/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, bb'[t] - c00 (1 - bb[t]) + d00 bb[t] ss[t] + 3 c00 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0};
  cinits = {ss[t /; t <= 0] == s0, bb[t /; t <= 0] == b0};
  ODES = Join[odes, cinits];
  solode = Quiet@NDSolve[ODES, {ss, bb}, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[8]]}][[1]];
  Return[Sum[Norm[{y1[[k]], k y2[[k]]} - 
  Evaluate[{ss[t], k bb[t]} /. solode /. {t -> tk[[k]]}]], {k, 1, 8}]]]
```

we obtain

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, the best thing would be to carry out a formulation according to maximum likelyhood to have a statistical idea. That is not my speciality.

Comment: It would require a proper approach, using `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: is a weighting factor, to give more importance to data far from the origin.

Comment: There are some examples in Wolfram repositories.

Comment: Why are you weighting "to give more importance to data far from the origin" and why weighting only the "B" values?

Comment: Because `B` values have a lower dispersion than `S`,  mainly near the data set end.

Comment: Thanks.  That is certainly a reason but if one is going to include weighting why not weight by the `Around` values for both S and B?  And why the norm and not the usual square of the norm? The bigger issue, however, is trying to estimate 5 parameters with just 8 data points and adding a somewhat arbitrary weighting seems excessive tweaking.

Comment: As I commented previously, a good focus may be to formulate according to the maximum likelyhood, thus including statistical data.

Comment: I agree:  maximum likelihood is the way to go.  Unfortunately *Mathematica* does not offer a high-level mixed model function (i.e., more than one source of error - in this case it would be measurement error and lack-of-fit error) for linear models or nonlinear models.