# Step size issue with ParametricNDSolveValue to fit data to a set of non linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am fitting dataset `dset` to a set of non-linear differential equations to find the fitting parameters `dP` (pressure differential) and `LK` (thermodynamic tension)

```
dset = {{0.0005`, -0.010556322978021847`}, {0.010500000000000006`, \
-0.16182647440121997`}, {0.020500000000000015`, \
-0.29695349218330797`}, {0.030500000000000024`, \
-0.4182634329865751`}, {0.04050000000000003`, -0.5269223967724705`}, \
{0.05050000000000004`, -0.6240338483581807`}, {0.06050000000000005`, \
-0.7106407676192987`}, {0.07050000000000005`, -0.7877204571404507`}, \
{0.08050000000000006`, -0.856181218817242`}, {0.09050000000000007`, \
-0.9168613181414874`}, {0.10050000000000008`, -0.9705298179210835`}, \
{0.11050000000000008`, -1.0178887965803456`}, {0.1205000000000001`, \
-1.059576525235709`}, {0.1305000000000001`, -1.096171257192166`}, \
{0.1405000000000001`, -1.1281953593331848`}, {0.1505000000000001`, \
-1.1561195807387954`}, {0.16050000000000011`, -1.1803673085219024`}, \
{0.17050000000000012`, -1.2013187048750018`}, {0.18050000000000013`, \
-1.219314653893368`}, {0.19050000000000014`, -1.2346604733142499`}, \
{0.20050000000000015`, -1.247629366294407`}, {0.21050000000000016`, \
-1.2584656030266932`}, {0.22050000000000017`, -1.2673874324894605`}, \
{0.23050000000000018`, -1.2745897318716903`}, {0.24050000000000019`, \
-1.2802464059943979`}, {0.25050000000000017`, -1.284512551975971`}, \
{0.2605000000000002`, -1.2875264059562497`}, {0.2705000000000002`, \
-1.2894110892831467`}, {0.2805000000000002`, -1.2902761714693076`}, \
{0.2905000000000002`, -1.2902190666663456`}, {0.3005000000000002`, \
-1.289326279545788`}, {0.3105000000000002`, -1.2876745154405251`}, \
{0.32050000000000023`, -1.2853316684758496`}, {0.33050000000000024`, \
-1.2823577002670472`}, {0.34050000000000025`, -1.2788054206235198`}, \
{0.35050000000000026`, -1.2747211806057743`}, {0.36050000000000026`, \
-1.2701454872488802`}, {0.3705000000000003`, -1.2651135483041822`}, \
{0.3805000000000003`, -1.259655754464611`}, {0.3905000000000003`, \
-1.2537981057286822`}, {0.4005000000000003`, -1.2475625878223087`}, \
{0.4105000000000003`, -1.2409675039324466`}, {0.4205000000000003`, \
-1.2340277664078854`}, {0.4305000000000003`, -1.2267551525451035`}, \
{0.44050000000000034`, -1.2191585280958825`}, {0.45050000000000034`, \
-1.2112440417030041`}, {0.46050000000000035`, -1.2030152930855527`}, \
{0.47050000000000036`, -1.1944734774498176`}, {0.48050000000000037`, \
-1.1856175082766092`}, {0.4905000000000004`, -1.1764441200214577`}};

fset = {{0.0005`, 0.0029994884862318545`}, {0.010500000000000006`, 
    0.04290422551646877`}, {0.020500000000000015`, 
    0.08271521578894832`}, {0.030500000000000024`, 
    0.1225075890771862`}, {0.04050000000000003`, 
    0.16232844620349135`}, {0.05050000000000004`, 
    0.2022016182928511`}, {0.06050000000000005`, 
    0.24213173178259795`}, {0.07050000000000005`, 
    0.2821076803700469`}, {0.08050000000000006`, 
    0.32210558852161697`}, {0.09050000000000007`, 
    0.36209133779687963`}, {0.10050000000000008`, 
    0.4020227165941489`}, {0.11050000000000008`, 
    0.44185124530069814`}, {0.1205000000000001`, 
    0.4815237217048463`}, {0.1305000000000001`, 
    0.5209835255288894`}, {0.1405000000000001`, 
    0.5601717158155678`}, {0.1505000000000001`, 
    0.599027950470219`}, {0.16050000000000011`, 
    0.6374912534028201`}, {0.17050000000000012`, 
    0.6755006513403476`}, {0.18050000000000013`, 
    0.7129956994240441`}, {0.19050000000000014`, 
    0.7499169121163021`}, {0.20050000000000015`, 
    0.7862061136751125`}, {0.21050000000000016`, 
    0.8218067204737102`}, {0.22050000000000017`, 
    0.8566639657168472`}, {0.23050000000000018`, 
    0.8907250756040312`}, {0.24050000000000019`, 
    0.9239394046879505`}, {0.25050000000000017`, 
    0.9562585370494301`}, {0.2605000000000002`, 
    0.9876363589372191`}, {0.2705000000000002`, 
    1.0180291076824612`}, {0.2805000000000002`, 
    1.0473954009765578`}, {0.2905000000000002`, 
    1.075696249981966`}, {0.3005000000000002`, 
    1.1028950592146718`}, {0.3105000000000002`, 
    1.1289576156826286`}, {0.32050000000000023`, 
    1.1538520693758882`}, {0.33050000000000024`, 
    1.1775489068722165`}, {0.34050000000000025`, 
    1.200020919538734`}, {0.35050000000000026`, 
    1.2212431675685949`}, {0.36050000000000026`, 
    1.241192940885903`}, {0.3705000000000003`, 
    1.2598497177767924`}, {0.3805000000000003`, 
    1.277195121955397`}, {0.3905000000000003`, 
    1.2932128786464807`}, {0.4005000000000003`, 
    1.3078887701584572`}, {0.4105000000000003`, 
    1.3212105913286585`}, {0.4205000000000003`, 
    1.3331681051444677`}, {0.4305000000000003`, 
    1.343752998777381`}, {0.44050000000000034`, 
    1.3529588402103094`}, {0.45050000000000034`, 
    1.3607810355900682`}, {0.46050000000000035`, 
    1.3672167873955854`}, {0.47050000000000036`, 
    1.372265053476814`}, {0.48050000000000037`, 
    1.375926506987712`}, {0.4905000000000004`, 1.3782034971952344`}};

cset = {{0.0005`, -0.5042310407443639`}, {0.010500000000000006`, \
-0.427674601050752`}, {0.020500000000000015`, -0.3544091437700765`}, \
{0.030500000000000024`, -0.28474223380967734`}, \
{0.04050000000000003`, -0.21845219304523977`}, {0.05050000000000004`, \
-0.1553452433932613`}, {0.06050000000000005`, -0.09525380897089007`}, \
{0.07050000000000005`, -0.038030681942581725`}, {0.08050000000000006`,
     0.016455923730000113`}, {0.09050000000000007`, 
    0.0683261356767569`}, {0.10050000000000008`, 
    0.11769117737156293`}, {0.11050000000000008`, 
    0.164655332408679`}, {0.1205000000000001`, 
    0.2093173133085545`}, {0.1305000000000001`, 
    0.25177119317041247`}, {0.1405000000000001`, 
    0.29210702401667615`}, {0.1505000000000001`, 
    0.33041123620685403`}, {0.16050000000000011`, 
    0.36676688931358775`}, {0.17050000000000012`, 
    0.4012538259126424`}, {0.18050000000000013`, 
    0.43394876511503755`}, {0.19050000000000014`, 
    0.4649253615923762`}, {0.20050000000000015`, 
    0.49425424760155606`}, {0.21050000000000016`, 
    0.5220030694835737`}, {0.22050000000000017`, 
    0.5482365257784656`}, {0.23050000000000018`, 
    0.5730164110488714`}, {0.24050000000000019`, 
    0.5964016674098069`}, {0.25050000000000017`, 
    0.6184484443671279`}, {0.2605000000000002`, 
    0.6392101666770944`}, {0.2705000000000002`, 
    0.6587376094076599`}, {0.2805000000000002`, 
    0.677078979099448`}, {0.2905000000000002`, 
    0.6942799998106967`}, {0.3005000000000002`, 
    0.7103840028276676`}, {0.3105000000000002`, 
    0.7254320188886919`}, {0.32050000000000023`, 
    0.7394628718770215`}, {0.33050000000000024`, 
    0.7525132730649463`}, {0.34050000000000025`, 
    0.764617915125826`}, {0.35050000000000026`, 
    0.7758095652630415`}, {0.36050000000000026`, 
    0.7861191569301358`}, {0.3705000000000003`, 
    0.7955758797315625`}, {0.3805000000000003`, 
    0.8042072671971728`}, {0.3905000000000003`, 
    0.8120392822155327`}, {0.4005000000000003`, 
    0.8190963999917696`}, {0.4105000000000003`, 
    0.8254016884657382`}, {0.4205000000000003`, 
    0.8309768861869055`}, {0.4305000000000003`, 
    0.8358424776946949`}, {0.44050000000000034`, 
    0.8400177664982754`}, {0.45050000000000034`, 
    0.8435209457891544`}, {0.46050000000000035`, 
    0.8463691670545794`}, {0.47050000000000036`, 
    0.8485786067907134`}, {0.48050000000000037`, 
    0.8501645315425272`}, {0.4905000000000004`, 0.8511413615178258`}};
```

[image]

below are the equations and the model for fitting the data

```
c0 = -4.0;

eqn1 = c'[s] == (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s];

eqn2 = f'[s] == 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2];

eqn3 = d'[s] == -(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK c[s] + 
      dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s])/Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2];

system = {eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, f[0.0005] == 0.0029994884862318545`, d[0.0005] == -0.010556322978021847`, c[0.0005] == -0.5042310407443639`};

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, d, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}, {dP, LK}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

I get an error in execution when I try to use the entire `dset` for fitting. And although I get the correct fitting parameter values for `dP` and `LK`, this happens when I use a subset i.e. `dset[[;;ind]]` where `ind` is less than 38; in this case when the evaluation occurs, I get a complaint that the step size effectively goes to 0 at a particular value of `s`.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dset[[1 ;; 37]], model[dP, LK][s], {dP, LK}, s, Method -> "Gradient"];
(*ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At s == 0.37654293376950654`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.*)
fit["BestFitParameters"]
{dP -> 17.48, LK -> -39.9968} (*these values are correct as dset, fset and cset were generated using these fitting parameters*)
```

My question is how to avoid the step size from reaching zero and possibly use the entire dataset `dset` for fitting?

Comment: How long does it take to run the `fit =NonlinearModelFit[dset.....`?

Comment: @bmf with full `dset` NonlinearModelFit does not execute. Try `dset[[;;36]`

Comment: @AliHashmi It is not clear why do you use `dset` only, while `model` depends on `c` and `f` as well?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried using all the three including `cset` and `fset` but could not get the code to work. Do you have an idea how to incorporate them as well and make the function work. Thanks !

Comment: @AlexTrounev i even tried this approach of putting `cset`, `fset` and `dset` together but it seems that the solver get stuck. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations

Answer (score 2):

Good starting values are your best friends.  If you start with `{{dP, 17}, {LK, -41}}` and use all of the data, then `NonlinearModelFit` executes quickly with only one minor warning:

[image: Warning message]

A plot of the fit is

```
Show[ListPlot[dset], Plot[fit[s], {s, Min[dset[[All, 1]]], Max[dset[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

The estimated root mean square error is

```
Sqrt[fit["EstimatedVariance"]]
(* 5.89791*10^-8 *)
```

Is that close enough to zero for your objective?

The parameter estimators are highly correlated and that many times spells trouble for getting convergence and/or avoiding warning messages.

```
fit["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Correlation matrix for parameter estimators]

**Further investigation**

It might be closer to the truth that "avoiding some starting values" rather than "choosing starting values closer to the optimal values" is the determining factor.  Typically, "closer to the optimal values" is needed to avoid getting lost in a bumpy/treacherous log likelihood surface.  But that doesn't seem to be the case here.

The problem seems to be that there are certain pairs of $dP$ and $LK$ that never return a value for `model[dP, LK][s]` and therefore stop `NonlinearModelFit` from completing.

Rather than the log likelihood surface, I'll construct the equivalent root mean square error for various pairs of `dP` and `LK`.  To avoid getting stuck with annoying pairs of `dP` and `LK`, the `TimeConstrained` function will be used to skip the troublemakers after some fixed amount of time.

```
rmse[dP_?NumericQ, LK_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[Sum[(dset[[i, 2]] - model[dP, LK][dset[[i, 1]]])^2, 
 {i, Length[dset]}]/(Length[dset] - 2)]
```

Generate values to use in `ListContourPlot`:

```
t = ConstantArray[{-1, -1, -1}, 15000];
k = 0;
Do[
  Do[
   k = k + 1;
   t[[k]] = {dP, LK, TimeConstrained[rmse[dP, LK], 0.1, -2]},
   {dP, 0, 25, 1/3}],
  {LK, -45, 2, 1/3}];
tGood = Select[t, #[[3]] > 0 &];
tBad = Select[t, #[[3]] == -2 &];
```

Show results:

```
Show[ListContourPlot[tGood, Contours -> 100, PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"dP", "LK"}],
 ListPlot[{tBad[[All, {1, 2}]], {{1, 1}}, {{17.5, -39.9}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, {PointSize[0.02], Green}, {PointSize[0.02],  Cyan}},
  PlotLegends -> {"Gets stuck", "Default starting values", "Values that minimize RMSE"}]]
```

[image: Contour plot of root mean square error surface]

An example of a set of parameter values that gets stuck is

```
model[21, -31][30]
```

I don't know why.

Comment: `{{dP, 5}, {LK, -1}}` works well, too, as starting values.  I suppose telling `NonlinearModelFit` that `LK` could be negative is the most influential reason for convergence given the high negative correlation between the two parameter estimators.

Comment: the staring range like `{{dP,5}, {LK,-1}}` can work as well for starting values. The only issue is that when fitting sometimes one may not even know a good defining range for the parameters. Can you let me know how can you define `LK < 0` as a constraint in `NonlinearModelFit`? Perhaps this suggestion of yours can be incorporated in the answer that I have posted below

Comment: You can change `model[dP, LK][s]` to `{model[dP, LK][s], LK < 0}` but you'll also need to give an explicit negative starting value as the default starting values are all 1.  The documentation for `NonlinearModelFit` has more details.

Comment: i will go through your answer in detail especially the choice of starting values. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer that I was looking for but based on @AlexTrounev 's comment, I added `dset` and `cset` for fitting the model. Addition of `fset` was causing trouble - I do not know the reason why - so I omitted it from the fitting procedure. I tried with various methods and the code below seems to work fine. Moreover, I added `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}` to `ParametricNDSolve`.

Why I can only take partial subset of the entire dataset for the fitting procedure is still a mystery to me (here I take values for which abscissa `s < 0.25`. All procedures give the correct fits for this cutoff. Except for `InteriorPoint` and `Newton` all other
methods give the correct fitting parameters until `s < 0.30`)

```
c0 = -4.0;
eqn1 = c'[s] == (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s];

eqn2 = f'[s] == 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2];

eqn3 = d'[
    s] == -(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + LK c[s] + 
      dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s])/Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2];
system = {eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, f[fset[[1, 1]]] == fset[[1, 2]], 
   d[dset[[1, 1]]] == dset[[1, 2]], c[cset[[1, 1]]] == cset[[1, 2]]};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  system, {c, d}, {s, 0.0005, 0.5}, {dP, LK}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}]
abscissae = dset[[All, 1]];
data = {cset[[All, 2]], dset[[All, 2]]};
transformedData = {ConstantArray[Range@Length[data],Length[abscissae]]//Transpose, 
    ConstantArray[abscissae, Length[data]], data}~Flatten~{{2, 3}, {1}};
model[dP_, LK_][i_, s_] := Through[sol[dP, LK][s], List][[i]]/;And@@NumericQ/@{dP, LK, i, s};
```

here are the methods that I tried in `NonlinearModelFit`

````
Monitor[fit = 
   Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData, {_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}], 
     model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s}, Method -> Automatic], {dP,LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.479913430292985`, LK -> -39.99712108751334`}

Monitor[fit = 
   Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData, {_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}], 
     model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s},Method -> "Gradient"], {dP, LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.479912619463647`, LK -> -39.99712090614286`}

Monitor[fit = 
Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData,{_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}],
 model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"], {dP,LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.4799737562324`, LK -> -39.997400761203224`}

Monitor[fit = 
   Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData, {_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}], 
     model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s},Method -> "InteriorPoint"], {dP, LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.479910658502142`, LK -> -39.997119423303715`}

Monitor[fit = 
   Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData, {_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}], 
     model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s}, Method -> "Newton"], {dP,LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.47991042033268`, LK -> -39.99712109812271`}

Monitor[fit = 
   Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData, {_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}], 
     model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s},Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"], {dP,LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.479913430292985`, LK -> -39.99712108751334`}

Monitor[fit = 
   Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Cases[transformedData, {_, x_ /; x < 0.25, _}], 
     model[dP, LK][i, s], {dP, LK}, {i, s}, Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}], {dP,LK}];
fit["BestFitParameters"] (*done*)
{dP -> 17.479912088798113`, LK -> -39.99711877609685`}
```
````

Comment: This is very good attempt (+1). How your data `cset, dset, fset` been generated? Could you show error as well?

Comment: @AlexTrounev sure will post this as a second question and link it with this one. I solved the three differential equations using a custom code that already existed (combination of Runge Kutta and Newton Raphson method to satisfy boundary conditions I guess). In this case the author did not use `NDSolve`. I will post this as a separate question because I am fairly confident that experts like yourself who know `NDSolve` inside out can use the built in function to solve the equations more conveniently.

Comment: @AlexTrounev here I have posted a separate question as to how I used a custom code to generate some of the data above and whether `NDSolve` can replace the custom code? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280489/replacing-custom-built-code-to-solve-helfrich-model-with-ndsolve