# Replacing custom built code to solve Helfrich model with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Helfrich model is a set of non-linear differential equations in physics that are used to determine the shape of a biological cell given pressure differential `dP` (inside and outside the cell) and thermodynamic tension `LK`. It was first successfully used to explain the biconcave shape of red blood cells.

I have a custom built code (written by someone else) that solves the equations but I am wondering if there is an easy way to take advantage of the built-in functionality of `NDSolve` to get similar result? Below I mention the algorithm that solves the equation and provide the custom code.

```
(*algorithm : solving the helfrich eqns *)
  
equations for dependent variable are f'[s], c'[s] and d'[s] are provided. s is the independent variable;

c'=(-2 dSqrt[1 - f c^2])/f;

f'=4Sqrt[1 - f c^2];

d'=-(2c^2(d-c0)+c(c0^2-d^2)+LK c +dP + 4 d(1-f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2];

we are solving them below with a combination of RK4 and Newton method (ensuring the boundary conditions are satisfied).

Detailed Procedure:

we assume dP=17.48 and c0 = -4;
(1) take some arbitrary initial test values where x -> c[0], y -> c[0.5], z -> d[0.5] and \[Beta], a flag set to True;
(2) while \[Beta] remains true:
    Compute thermodynamic tension LK. This is computed at s = 0.5 for convenience.
    LK = 2 y (c0-z)+z^2-c0^2-(dP/y);
  
    Feed the 3 eqns (eqn1,eqn2,eqn3) to sisRK4 ---> c with value x, f with value 0.001, d with 
    value 0.0 and s with value 0.0 and 0.5; (see code below)
   sisRK4 will compute updated values for c,f and d;

(3) obtain new values of c, f and d at s = 0.5 i.e. cN,fN and dN and compare values with the boundary condition. 
The comparisons are f1,f2,f3.

    f1=Abs[y*Sqrt[fN]-1];
    f2=Abs[y-cN];
    f3=Abs[z-dN];  

    (4)  if these values agree with the BCs to a defined tolerance then we have the solution Sol.

    else we apply the newton's method:

    we sequentially increase x, y and z by a small amount hx, hy, hz and compute new LK and RK4
to find estimates of c,f and d at 0.5 .. new error estimates {f1x,f2x,f3x}, {f1y,f2y,f3y}, {f1z,f2z,f3z} are made
and derivatives of error are computed from (f1x - f1)/hx etc to from the Jacobian matrix. From the inverse of
Jacobian matrix and error vector {f1,f2,f3} new test values are determined by using:
{x,y,z} = {x,y,z} - Inverse[Jacobian].{f1,f2,f3}

Procedure is repeated until convergence is achieved within a specified tolerance.
*)
```

The code for the procedure above is provided as follows:

```
(*the function sisRK4 integrates equations using RK4*)
sisRK4[{p_, q_, r_}, {s_, s0_, sn_}, {c_, c0_}, {f_, f0_}, {d_, d0_}, 
   steps_] := Block[{sold = s0, cold = c0, fold = f0, dold = d0,
    sollist = {{s0, c0, f0, d0}}, s, c, f, d, h},
   h = N[(sn - s0)/steps];
   Do[
    rule = {s -> sold, c -> cold, f -> fold, d -> dold};
    snew = sold + h;
    k1 = h (p /. rule);
    l1 = h (q /. rule);
    m1 = h (r /. rule);
    rule = {s -> sold + h/2., c -> cold + k1/2., f -> fold + l1/2., 
      d -> dold + m1/2.};
    k2 = h (p /. rule);
    l2 = h (q /. rule);
    m2 = h (r /. rule);
    rule = {s -> sold + h/2., c -> cold + k2/2., f -> fold + l2/2., 
      d -> dold + m2/2.};
    k3 = h (p /. rule);
    l3 = h (q /. rule);
    m3 = h (r /. rule);
    rule = {s -> sold + h, c -> cold + k3, f -> fold + l3, 
      d -> dold + m3};
    k4 = h (p /. rule);
    l4 = h (q /. rule);
    m4 = h (r /. rule);
    cnew = cold + (1/6.) (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4);
    fnew = fold + (1/6.) (l1 + 2 l2 + 2 l3 + l4);
    dnew = dold + (1/6.) (m1 + 2 m2 + 2 m3 + m4);
    AppendTo[sollist, {snew, cnew, fnew, dnew}];
    sold = snew;
    cold = cnew;
    fold = fnew;
    dold = dnew,
    steps
    ];
   sollist
   ];
```

```
ClearAll[s, c, f, d, h];
c0 = -4.0;
dP = 17.48;
(*initial test values*)
x = -0.8;
y = 0.8;
z = -0.6;
\[Beta] = True;

While[\[Beta],
  LK = 2 y (c0 - z) + z^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y);
  Sol = sisRK4[{c' = (-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, f' = 4 Sqrt[1 - f c^2],
      d' = -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + LK c + dP + 
         4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]}, {s, 0.0, 0.5}, {c, 
     x}, {f, 0.001}, {d, 0.0}, 1000];
  (*obtained values at s=0.5 *)
  cN = Sol[[1001, 2]];
  fN = Sol[[1001, 3]];
  dN = Sol[[1001, 4]];
  
  (*checking for the boundary conditions*)
  f1 = Abs[y*Sqrt[fN] - 1];
  f2 = Abs[y - cN];
  f3 = Abs[z - dN];
  
  \[Beta] = If[f1 < 0.001 && f2 < 0.001 && f3 < 0.001, False, True];
  
  (*application of Newton Method*)
  If[\[Beta],
   (*partial derivatives in x*)
   hx = 0.001;
   x2 = x + hx;
   LK = 2 y (c0 - z) + z^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y);
   Sol = 
    sisRK4[{c' = (-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, f' = 4 Sqrt[1 - f c^2], 
      d' = -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + LK c + dP + 
          4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]}, {s, 0.0, 0.5}, {c, 
      x2}, {f, 0.001}, {d, 0.0}, 1000];
   cNx = Sol[[1001, 2]];
   fNx = Sol[[1001, 3]];
   dNx = Sol[[1001, 4]];
   
   f1x = Abs[y*Sqrt[fNx] - 1];
   f2x = Abs[y - cNx];
   f3x = Abs[z - dNx];
   
   (*partial derivatives in y*)
   hy = 0.001;
   y2 = y + hy;
   LK = 2 y2 (c0 - z) + z^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y2);
   Sol = 
    sisRK4[{c' = (-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, f' = 4 Sqrt[1 - f c^2], 
      d' = -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + LK c + dP + 
          4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]}, {s, 0.0, 0.5}, {c, 
      x}, {f, 0.001}, {d, 0.0}, 1000];
   cNy = Sol[[1001, 2]];
   fNy = Sol[[1001, 3]];
   dNy = Sol[[1001, 4]];
   
   f1y = Abs[y2*Sqrt[fNy] - 1];
   f2y = Abs[y2 - cNy];
   f3y = Abs[z - dNy];
   
   (*partial derivatives in z*)
   hz = 0.001;
   z2 = z + hz;
   LK = 2 y (c0 - z2) + z2^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y);
   Sol = 
    sisRK4[{c' = (-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, f' = 4 Sqrt[1 - f c^2], 
      d' = -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + LK c + dP + 
          4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]}, {s, 0.0, 0.5}, {c, 
      x}, {f, 0.001}, {d, 0.0}, 1000];
   cNz = Sol[[1001, 2]];
   fNz = Sol[[1001, 3]];
   dNz = Sol[[1001, 4]];
   
   f1z = Abs[y*Sqrt[fNz] - 1];
   f2z = Abs[y - cNz];
   f3z = Abs[z2 - dNz];
   
   (*constructing the Jacobian Matrix*)
   Jf = ( {
      {(f1x - f1)/hx, (f1y - f1)/hy, (f1z - f1)/hz},
      {(f2x - f2)/hx, (f2y - f2)/hy, (f2z - f2)/hz},
      {(f3x - f3)/hx, (f3y - f3)/hy, (f3z - f3)/hz}
     } );
   
   Vectorf = {f1, f2, f3};
   Vectorx = {x, y, z};
   Vectorx2 = Vectorx - Inverse[Jf] . Vectorf;
   (* New test values*)
   {x, y, z} = Vectorx2;
   ];
  ];
(*creating matrices that represent c,f and d as a function of S*)
cvar = Sol[[All, {1, 2}]];
fvar = Sol[[All, {1, 3}]];
dvar = Sol[[All, {1, 4}]];

(*Plotting the curvatures*)
plotcurvatures = 
 ListPlot[{cvar, fvar, dvar}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotLegends -> {"c", "f", "d"}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["S", 25, Italic]], 
    Text[Style["Curvature", 25, Italic]]}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Black, Italic], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 22], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker@Green}, AspectRatio -> 0.6, 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

Comment: How to set boundary conditions for `NDSolve`? From this explanation it looks like `LK == 2 c[0.5] (c0 - d[0.5]) + d[0.5]^2 - c0^2 - (dP/c[0.5]),c[0.5] Sqrt[f[0.5]] == 1, f[0]==10^-3, d[0]==0`. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexTrounev that is correct !

Comment: With these input data there is exact solution `d[s]=0, c[s]=1,f[s]=(1 + 120 Sqrt[1110] s - 4000 s^2)/1000`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev could you kindly post your answer as a solution. In the question I was wondering can we use  `NDSolve` to find solution to the set of equations more conveniently than the custom code. Maybe a combination of NDSolve and FindRoot. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexTrounev what if a different value of `dP` is used. Here I just fixed it to 17.48

Comment: @AlexTrounev is it possible to form a chat group where I can discuss the issue that I am facing with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With input data `d[0]==0,LK = 2 c[0.5] (c0 - d[0.5]) + d[0.5]^2 - c0^2 - (dP/c[0.5])` there is exact solution for any `f[0]=f0, dP` in the form

```
{{f -> Function[{s}, f0 - 4 Sqrt[1 - c^2 f0] s - 4 c^2 s^2]}, {f -> 
   Function[{s}, f0 + 4 Sqrt[1 - c^2 f0] s - 4 c^2 s^2]}}
{{c -> -(Sqrt[-f0 - Sqrt[4 + f0^2]]/Sqrt[2])}, {c -> 
   Sqrt[-f0 - Sqrt[4 + f0^2]]/Sqrt[
   2]}, {c -> -(Sqrt[-f0 + Sqrt[4 + f0^2]]/Sqrt[2])}, {c -> 
   Sqrt[-f0 + Sqrt[4 + f0^2]]/Sqrt[2]}}
```

It is very intriguing that `NDSolve` can't compute this solution for particular initial conditions `f[0]==10^-3, c[0.5] Sqrt[f[0.5]] == 1`, but we can compute it with the Euler wavelets collocation method as follows

```
eqn = {(-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, 4 Sqrt[1 - f c^2],
   -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + 
       c (c0^2 - d^2) + (2 c[0.5] (c0 - d[0.5]) + d[0.5]^2 - 
          c0^2 - (dP/c[0.5])) c + dP + 4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/
    Sqrt[1 - f c^2]} /. {c[0.5] -> c, d -> 0, d[0.5] -> 0, c0 -> -4,dP -> 1748/100};
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
A = Array[a, {nn, 3}]; B = Array[b, {3}];(*y=2 s*)
U1[y_] := Psi[y] . A; U[y_] := int1[y] . A + B;

eqs[y_] := -2 U1[y] + eqn /. {c -> U[y][[1]], f -> U[y][[2]], 
    d -> U[y][[3]], c[0.5] -> U[1][[1]], f[0.5] -> U[1][[2]], 
    d[0.5] -> U[1][[3]]};

bc = {c[0.5] Sqrt[f[0.5]] == 1, f[0] == 10^-3, 
    d[0] == 0} /. {c[0.5] -> U[1][[1]], f[0.5] -> U[1][[2]], 
    d[0.5] -> U[1][[3]], f[0] -> U[0][[2]], d[0] -> U[0][[3]]};

eqAll = Join[Flatten[Table[eqs[y][[i]] == 0, {y, ycol}, {i, 3}]], 
  bc]; var = Join[Flatten[A], B];

sol = FindRoot[eqAll, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxIterations -> 1000];
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[U[2 s] /. sol]], {s, 0, .5}, PlotLegends -> {"c", "f", "d"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Therefore, in this case exact solution is

```
d[s]=0, c[s]=1,f[s]=(1 + 120 Sqrt[1110] s - 4000 s^2)/1000
```

Actually we can compute exact like solution with `ParametricNDSolve` as follows

```
Remove["Global`*"]; ClearAll["Global`*"];

eq = With[{c = c[s], f = f[s], d = d[s]}, 
  D[{c, f, d}, s] - {(-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, 
     4 Sqrt[1 - 
        f c^2], -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + (LK) c + dP + 
         4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]} /. {c0 -> -4, 
    dP -> 1748/100}];

bc1 = {c[0] == p, f[0] == 10^-3, d[0] == 0}; eq1 = 
 Join[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, 3}], bc1];

sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[eq1, {c, f, d}, {s, 0, 1/2}, {p, LK}];

cfun = c /. sol1; ffun = f /. sol1; dfun = d /. sol1;

sol2 = FindRoot[{cfun[p, LK][1/2] Sqrt[ffun[p, LK][1/2]] == 1, 
   LK == 2 cfun[p, LK][1/2] (c0 - dfun[p, LK][1/2]) + 
      dfun[p, LK][1/2]^2 - c0^2 - (dP/cfun[p, LK][1/2]) /. {c0 -> -4, 
     dP -> 1748/100}}, {{p, 1}, {LK, -(1037/25)}}];
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[{cfun[p, LK][s], ffun[p, LK][s], dfun[p, LK][s]} /. 
   sol2], {s, 0, .5}, PlotLegends -> {"c", "f", "d"}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

The question is what solution we compute with the code `sisRK4`?

Update 1. The model we used above has been taken from this [paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/10.0003452). The difference is that they put `f[0]==0` while we put `f[0]==10^-3` as Ali Hashmi proposed. With the new boundary condition we can solve this problem using the Haar wavelets collocation method as follows

```
h[x_, k_, m_] := 
  WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - k, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity];
p[x_, k_, m_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1 + k - m*x)/m, 
     k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x < 0 && 1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && 
      m > 0}, {(-k + m*x)/m, 
     k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x >= 0 && k/m - x < 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}}, 0];
h1[x_] := WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity];
p1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 1}}, x];
J = 8; M = 2^J;
dt = 1/(2*M); tl = Table[l dt, {l, 0, 2 M}];
Tcol = Table[(tl[[l - 1]] + tl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}];
U1[k_][t_] := 
  Sum[v[k][i, j] h[t, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   v1[k] h1[t];
U0[k_][t_] := 
  Sum[v[k][i, j] p[t, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   v1[k] p1[t] + v2[k];
varAll = {c, f, d}; s0 = {p, 0, 
  0}; F = {(-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, 
   4 Sqrt[1 - 
      f c^2], -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + (LK) c + dP + 
       4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]} /. {c0 -> -4, 
   dP -> 1748/100}; m = 3; varM = 
 Join[Flatten[Table[{v2[k], v1[k]}, {k, m}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    v[k][i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}, {k, 
     m}]], {LK}]; rult = Table[varAll[[k]] -> U0[k][t], {k, m}]; LK0 =
  2 c[0.5] (c0 - d[0.5]) + d[0.5]^2 - 
    c0^2 - (dP/c[0.5]) /. {c[0.5] -> U0[1][1], f[0.5] -> U0[2][1], 
    d[0.5] -> U0[3][1]} /. {c0 -> -4, dP -> 1748/100};
bc = {c[0.5] Sqrt[f[0.5]] == 1, f[0] == 0, d[0] == 0, 
    LK == LK0} /. {c[0.5] -> U0[1][1], f[0.5] -> U0[2][1], 
    d[0.5] -> U0[3][1], f[0] -> U0[2][0], d[0] -> U0[3][0]};

eq = Flatten[
  Table[2 U1[k][t] == F[[k]] /. rult, {t, Tcol}, {k, m}]]; sol = 
 FindRoot[Join[eq, bc], 
  Table[{varM[[i]], RandomReal[{1/5, 1/2}]}, {i, Length[varM]}], 
  MaxIterations -> 1000];
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Re[U0[k][2 s] /. sol], {k, 3}]], {s, 0, .5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"c", "f", "d"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}, {Green}}]
```

These data (doted lines) we can compare with `sisRK4` results (solid lines)
[image: Figure 3]

Note, the code above has not been tested for every run. If `sol` converges then it should be solution as above.

We can also solve this problem with parametric `NDSolve`. To avoid singularity at `f->0`, we use rule `d/f=d'/f'` at `f->0, d->0`. With this rule we solve equations at first step `h = 10^-8`. Therefore we have

```
    eq = With[{c = c[s], f = f[s], d = d[s]}, 
   D[{c, f, d}, s] - {(-2 d Sqrt[1 - f c^2])/f, 
     4 Sqrt[1 - 
        f c^2], -(2 c^2 (d - c0) + c (c0^2 - d^2) + (LK) c + dP + 
         4 d (1 - f c^2)/f)/Sqrt[1 - f c^2]}];
h = 10^-8; ic = { c[h] == p + h/4 (dP + c0^2 p + LK p - 2 c0 p^2), 
  f[h] == 4 h, d[h] == h/2 (-dP - c0^2 p - LK p + 2 c0 p^2)}; eq1 = 
 Join[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, 3}], ic] /. {c0 -> -4, dP -> 1748/100};
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[eq1, {c, f, d}, {s, h, 1/2}, {p, LK}];

cfun = c /. sol1; ffun = f /. sol1; dfun = 
 d /. sol1; eqn = {cfun[p, LK][s] Sqrt[ffun[p, LK][s]] == 1, 
   LK == 2 cfun[p, LK][s] (c0 - dfun[p, LK][s]) + dfun[p, LK][s]^2 - 
     c0^2 - (dP/cfun[p, LK][s])} /. {c0 -> -4, dP -> 1748/100, 
   s -> 1/2};

sol2 = FindRoot[eqn, {{p, -1/2}, {LK, -40}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, 
  Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}]
(*{p -> -0.0684148292163831185884264856396, 
 LK -> -39.9768774596520202382742346701}*)
```

Visualization

```
    Plot[Evaluate[
      Re[{cfun[p, LK][s], ffun[p, LK][s], dfun[p, LK][s]}] /. sol2], {s, 
      h, .5}, PlotLegends -> {"c", "f", "d"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

This solution (thin solid lines) consider with the Haar wavelets collocation method (dotted lines), but differ from `sisRK4`
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: thanks. Is the variable `eqn` defined above? the code seems to be crashing when I am running it.

Comment: also Alex I was wondering whether the advanced `NDSolve` related functionality as listed here (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) can be used to compute `LK` from starting test values provided for `c[0], c[0.5], d[0]` before `NDSolve` computes anything else?

Comment: Sorry, expression for `eqn` has been added.

Comment: Hi Alex, i think it is still missing. For the context i mean the variable `eqn` in  `eqs[y_] := -2 U1[y] + eqn ...` is still not defined. thanks again

Comment: @AliHashmi Thank you for testing, now it looks like working code. Please, see also update with  `ParametricNDSolve` solution.

Comment: thanks Alex. actually with `dP = 17.48` and `c0=-4` the curves should look like this instead  https://imgur.com/a/l8LZ6Sg. It is correct as it has been reported in literature as well and can be generated by the code i have posted in question. In your case why does `c` and `d` are essentially constants for all values of `s`? At the end of the procedure (not shown in the post) the curvature `c` is integrated to get the shape of the object. It certainly should not be a constant

Comment: `d` is 0 at s=0 and `f` is 0 at s = 0 and we start from guess values `x,y,z` and improve our estimates of these values (see code in the question) until the boundary conditions are satisfied. sisRK4 is i guess the runge kutta scheme and the second part of the code (with Jacobian Matrix calculation) uses newton method to improve estimates of `x,y,z`. At least that is my thinking about the code in the question.

Comment: @AliHashmi I think that we need additional restriction for this model. Could you give a link to the report with picture you show?

Comment: I have created a google drive folder and link for you. There are two articles that I placed inside. you can choose to read anyone you like (the code posted in the question belongs to one of the articles and is present in the supplementary folder associated with one of the articles and presents further detail on how the authors solve/implement the model) : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UgTW3O0jSE5RTXOpkEeszw_nswuZMp_C?usp=sharing

Comment: @AliHashmi Thank you for the model clarification. As I understand you used equations (41), (42), (43), (44) from  American Journal of Physics 89, 465 (2021) and code they are proposed.

Comment: yes you are right. and equation 45 as well which are the boundary conditions to be satisfied. 44 is a constraint equation. and (41-43) are the main differential equations

Comment: If so then you need to put `f[0]==0` as in first equation (45). The difference between your solution with `f[0][==10^-3` and my solution with `f[0]==0` shown in Update 1 for my answer.

Comment: actually i am getting weird answers by running your scripts. I added `ClearAll` to remove any definitions and also tried to run your code in fresh kernel. I am getting strange answers.  can you kindly check what is happening by running your code one by one in a fresh kernel

Comment: @AliHashmi Sorry, some part of code has been removed occasionally.  Please, test again.

Comment: the code runs now but the issue is in the last piece of code. try changing `LK` to -60 in your code and you will see that the root for LK deviates a lot.  `sol2 = FindRoot[eqn, {{p, -1/2}, {LK, -40}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxIterations -> 1000,   Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}]`

Comment: @AliHashmi Yes, you are right. Nevertheless, we can use two consider solutions from above to test your code. Also, please pay attention that your code not reproduces exact solution.

Comment: fair point. actually this is how my solution below compares with yours. https://imgur.com/oVyF33d

Comment: @AliHashmi This is very good. Could you add this picture to your answer? Practically you have several codes for your future research.  The only question is how to reproduce exact solution with your code?

Comment: thanks. i added the plots and accepted your answer, As for your question, it is also a fairly open question for me too. for now my purpose is to assume some `dP` and generate the different shapes

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very useful discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how `NDSolve` can be modified to solve the model above. Although not the best or the most convenient implementation with the built-in function, The advanced features of `NDSolve` can give us control over changing the state of variable `LK` before computing anything else.

In crux, it is more or less the same code as the one I posted in the question with the only difference that I use `NDSolve` here to iterate the equations with `CRK4` method than `sisRK4` (in the question).

```
CRK4[{two_, half_, sixth_}]["Step"[rhs_, h_, t_, x_, xp_]] := 
  Module[{k4, k1, k2, k3},
   k1 = h xp;
   k2 = h rhs[t + half h, x + half k1];
   k3 = h rhs[t + half h, x + half k2];
   k4 = h rhs[t + h, x + k3];
   sixth (k1 + two (k2 + k3) + k4)
   ];

CRK4 /: NDSolve`InitializeMethod[CRK4, stepmode_, sd_, rhs_, state_, 
  opts___] := Module[{prec},
  prec = state@"WorkingPrecision";
  CRK4[N[{2, 1/2, 1/6}, prec]]
  ]
CRK4[___]["StepInput"] = {"F"["T", "X"], "H", "T", "X", "XP"};
CRK4[___]["StepOutput"] = "XI";
CRK4[___]["DifferenceOrder"] := 4
CRK4[___]["StepMode"] := Fixed

step = 0.0001; x = -0.8; y = 0.8; z = -0.6; c0 = -4.0; dP = 17.48; \
\[Beta] = True;
hx = step; hy = step; hz = step;

While[\[Beta],
  LK = 2 y (c0 - z) + (z)^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y);
  state = 
   First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{c'[
         s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0,
      f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0,
      d'[
         s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + 
             LK*c[s] + dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
           1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0,
      f[0] == 0.0001, c[0] == x, d[0] == 0.0}, {f, c, d}, {s, 0, 1/2}, 
     Method -> CRK4, StartingStepSize -> 0.0005];
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, 1/2];
  sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
  {fN, cN, dN} = {f[1/2], c[1/2], d[1/2]} /. sol;
  
  f1 = Abs[y Sqrt[fN] - 1];
  f2 = Abs[y - cN];
  f3 = Abs[z - dN];
  
  \[Beta] = If[f1 < 0.001 && f2 < 0.001 && f3 < 0.001, False, True];
  
  If[\[Beta],
   {x2, y2, z2} = {x + hx, y + hy, z + hz};
   
   LK = 2 y (c0 - z) + (z)^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y);
   state = 
    First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{c'[
          s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0,
       f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0,
       d'[
          s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + 
              LK*c[s] + dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
            1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0,
       f[0] == 0.0001, c[0] == x2, d[0] == 0.0}, {f, c, d}, {s, 0, 
       1/2}, Method -> CRK4, StartingStepSize -> 0.0005];
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, 1/2];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
   
   {fNx, cNx, dNx} = {f[1/2], c[1/2], d[1/2]} /. sol;
   f1x = Abs[y Sqrt[fNx] - 1];
   f2x = Abs[y - cNx];
   f3x = Abs[z - dNx];
   
   LK = 2 y2 (c0 - z) + (z)^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y2);
   state = 
    First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{c'[
          s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0,
       f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0,
       d'[
          s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + 
              LK*c[s] + dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
            1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0,
       f[0] == 0.0001, c[0] == x, d[0] == 0.0}, {f, c, d}, {s, 0, 1/2},
       Method -> CRK4, StartingStepSize -> 0.0005];
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, 1/2];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
   
   {fNy, cNy, dNy} = {f[1/2], c[1/2], d[1/2]} /. sol;
   f1y = Abs[y2 Sqrt[fNy] - 1];
   f2y = Abs[y2 - cNy];
   f3y = Abs[z - dNy];
   
   LK = 2 y (c0 - z2) + (z2)^2 - c0^2 - (dP/y);
   state = 
    First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{c'[
          s] - (-2 d[s] Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2])/f[s] == 0,
       f'[s] - 4 Sqrt[1 - f[s] c[s]^2] == 0,
       d'[
          s] - (-(2 c[s]^2 (d[s] - c0) + c[s] (c0^2 - d[s]^2) + 
              LK*c[s] + dP + 4 d[s] (1 - f[s] c[s]^2)/f[s]))/(Sqrt[
            1 - f[s] c[s]^2]) == 0,
       f[0] == 0.0001, c[0] == x, d[0] == 0.0}, {f, c, d}, {s, 0, 1/2},
       Method -> CRK4, StartingStepSize -> 0.0005];
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, 1/2];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
   
   {fNz, cNz, dNz} = {f[1/2], c[1/2], d[1/2]} /. sol;
   f1z = Abs[y Sqrt[fNz] - 1];
   f2z = Abs[y - cNz];
   f3z = Abs[z2 - dNz];
   
   Jf = ( {
      {(f1x - f1)/hx, (f1y - f1)/hy, (f1z - f1)/hz},
      {(f2x - f2)/hx, (f2y - f2)/hy, (f2z - f2)/hz},
      {(f3x - f3)/hx, (f3y - f3)/hy, (f3z - f3)/hz}
     } );
   
   {x, y, z} = {x, y, z} - Inverse[Jf] . {f1, f2, f3};
   ];
  ];
Print@{LK, {x, y, z}};

(*{-39.9958,{-0.0887335,0.864286,-1.10808}}*)

ListLinePlot[Evaluate[{c, f, d} /. sol], PlotStyle -> {"c", "f", "d"}]
```

[image]

also this compares fairly well with the solution posted by @Alex Trounev

[image]

Comment: Did you try to make a research with this code, for example, how solution converges with step decreasing?

Comment: @AlexTrounev no actually I did not change the step. I merely compared the answer here with the one I got from the code in the question. Essentially used NDSolve as the iterator here. Does it change in your opinion?

Comment: Actually your code is very good (+1) compare to published in the paper. My question is only about boundary condition `f[0]==10^-3` you used, while in the paper they used `f[0]==0`.

Comment: But this method is very sensitive to the step size decreasing. For example, for  `StartingStepSize -> 5 10^-5` we have `{-39.7464,{-0.443645,0.854412,-1.21378}}`, while for `StartingStepSize -> 5 10^-4` as above we have `{-39.8661,{-0.517524,0.852474,-1.19337}}`. Therefore solution is not converged.

Comment: Also for `StartingStepSize -> 2 10^-5` we have `{-39.9449,{-0.380249,0.853735,-1.16829}}`, and `c[0] /. sol` is about -0.380249 compare to -0.506871 at  `StartingStepSize -> 5 10^-4` .   Generally speaking we need to update this code so that the numerical solution converges with step size decreasing.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have updated this code and now I think it agrees fairly well with yours. I modified  the `step` variable to a lower value like `0.0001` as it was being used to computes the derivatives in the Jacobian during the Newton Method (via `hx`, `hy` and `hz` which were all set to the value of the `step` variable). Reducing it gives a fairly nice agreement with your answer. Of course I have also lowered `f[0]` to an even lower value but did not get a 100 percent agreement. I cannot use `f[0]=0` in this formulation as we get an indeterminate form.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now solution converges with step size decreasing to that we computed with the Euler wavelet collocation method.